# New Ask Question UI doesn't allow asker to upload image

Tags: feature-request, image-upload, ask-question-wizard-2018

I recently encountered a small yet important problem.

While, asking a question on Stack Overflow, there is a new UI, and there is no option to upload any image.

On clicking on image, it just gives this information;

> Images are exactly like links, but they have an exclamation point in front of them:
>
> ```
> ![a busy cat](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg)
> ![two muppets][1]
> ```

But upload image button is missing.

Take example of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54039422), I had to use a third party website to upload the first image. But then I had to upload another image as well, so in the `Edit Question` page there is still the old `UI`, due to which I was able to upload the second image right from SO.

So, take the needful action as soon as possible.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this is intentional. *Very rarely* do I ever see a new user upload an image for a legitimate reason.

Comment: @Carcigenicate So is that new `UI` only for new users?

Comment: Are you asking about the Wizard? I just clicked on "Ask question" and was met by the same screen I always have, and it contained the typical image upload button. Yes, I think you're seeing the new question wizard for new users which is intended to help new users ask better questions.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, I forget to mention that while typing this question on Meta I met the usual `UI`, that means, the new `UI` is only for SO not for Meta. Where did you tried? Meta or SO?

Comment: Meta. I'll try on the main site. Sec.

Comment: @Zathura the New Wizard isn't displayed to everyone. Depends on rep, question history, etc. I'd be surprised if a user with Carcigenicate's rep would be impacted

Comment: @Patrice,OK, that UI is only for new users, But still SO should provide a option to upload image just in case.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, I agree with this that new user uploads images very rarely, but if there would be an option to upload image, then this will not bother the user who don't want to upload image, but this will be *very* beneficial for whose who want to upload image.

Comment: @Zathura You may be one of the few newer users who know the intended purpose of images in questions. If a user really wants to post an image, they can edit it in after. An image is rarely ever required to ask a question properly; they're usually supplementary.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a change specific to the new question wizard. I can still upload images as before.

If the new question wizard disallows image uploads, I think this is likely intentional, and a *great* change. Rarely do questions ever require images. I think in my 4 years here and 100+ questions asked, I've only *needed* an image once, if that. The vast majority of the time new users are uploading images, it's for the wrong reasons. I can't count how many times in a day I see new users uploading images of code.

It's so bad that if I type "post" in my mobile keyboard, SwiftKey automatically begins populating the comment I leave on such questions; asking them to edit their code as text into the question itself.

I definitely support this change.

---

@Hans pointed out a flaw in my reasoning. Most code posted as pictures are done by very new users who don't have upload privileges anyways. This change doesn't prevent users from circumventing that block by uploading offsite and linking in the question.

It does still help with 10+ rep users who abuse image uploads though.

Unless such people are excluded from the Wizard. In that case, maybe I'm wrong? Maybe this doesn't help very much?

Comment: *SwiftKey automatically begins populating the comment I leave on such questions*, lol

Comment: New users are not allowed to upload images at all, not until they earn sufficient rep.  10 required.

Comment: @HansPassant Honestly, I wanted to write an answer, but ended up beinf rushed to get it out before my shift started, so I didn't entirely think that part through. I agree with the change as I think making uploading images harder us a good thing, but is retrospect, no, this doesn't prevent anyone from linking offsite, which is the majority of what happens. I'll add a bit.

Comment: @HansPassant I have 31 reps but still I'm getting the new `UI`

Comment: If the system categorizes a user as needing the wizard, the odds are extremely high that any uploaded images (or links, for that matter) detract from, rather than improve, the question. A sophisticated user who ends up using the wizard can add the image later. I agree that this lack of an image upload button is a *feature*, not a *bug*.

Comment: Note that on other SE sites, like [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com), images are very relevant, many questions are of the form 'this is my code, this is how the output pdf looks, this is how I want it to look'. We often ask first posters to provide a screenshot to make clear what the question is about exactly. Possibly for other SE sites it is also relevant (like Photography.SE). So if the wizard is deployed network-wide this issue should be addressed.

Comment: @Marijn This *is* the Stack Overflow Meta though, not the SE Meta.

Comment: @Carcigenicate it is, and I agree with your answer considering SO. But I thought it would be useful to note to the community here (and maybe SE devs looking for feedback?) that this issue may need to be reconsidered _if and when_ the wizard comes to other sites.

Comment: @Marijn Fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

The option is available in the final, "Review", step:

[image: Review tab]

In fact the review step (which does not require going through the previous steps) is essentially a copy of the regular ask page.

Comment: dunno, at the time I posted that question there was nothing like this.

Answer (score 2):

This is new UI, in guided mode

[image: Guided Mode]

and if you noticed, there is "Use traditional mode", which bring you back to old way when you click it.

[image: Traditional Mode]

[The Ask Question Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381671/the-ask-question-wizard-is-live)