# The Ask Question Wizard (2018) is Live!

Tags: discussion, ask-question-wizard-2018, announcement, ask-question-form

<sup>Editors note: For the Ask Question Wizard 2022 see [Feature Test: Ask Wizard for New Users (trial has completed)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416322)</sup>

---

I'm really happy to announce that the [Ask Question Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard) is now live on Stack Overflow! This is the end of a long arc of experiments that have been happening for over a year to provide structured guidance to newcomers when asking a question, and I'm so excited for everyone in the community to give it a go. This is the biggest change we've made to the question asking experience on Stack Overflow since we started a little over ten years ago, and it's the result of a lot of hard work and collaboration with all of you in the community.

[image: Guided mode]

#### How it works

1. Go to the [question asking page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). If you are under the reputation threshold (currently 111, because that's what we tested with in previous experiments), you will automatically be directed to the wizard, also known as **guided mode**. If you are over that threshold, you'll be taken to the original question asking page, which we're calling **traditional mode**.
2. You can switch from traditional to guided mode at any time by clicking the "Use guided mode" link near the top. When in guided mode, you'll be able to switch to traditional mode *after* first answering a few questions - a "Use traditional mode" link will appear when this is available.
3. After you've switched modes, future visits to the question asking page will direct you to the question asking mode you last used for a period of time, overriding the default described in #1. That way, you don't need to keep switching back and forth between the two experiences. After that time period expires, you'll again be directed to the default mode based on your reputation.
4. Switching between guided and traditional modes should always save your work once you start typing your question, so don't worry about losing any drafts when switching between the two modes. There might be slight differences in formatting when you switch, but the content of your post should always be preserved.

#### Why we're excited

Everyone on Stack Overflow stands to benefit from this feature:

1. Guided mode **addresses many of the concerns newcomers have about asking their first few questions**.

   There is a lot of guidance, history, and culture involved in asking a question, and filling out those few blank boxes in the original question asking page can feel like a daunting task. With guided mode, we've tried our best to bake in many of the best practices when asking a good question on Stack Overflow. We're hoping that, with this launch, asking a question can turn from an intimidating experience into one that is more approachable and even fun.
2. Guided mode means **better questions on the site overall**.

   Based on our experiments, we found that [question quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302970/how-is-question-quality-measured-in-a-b-tests) improved when using guided mode compared to traditional mode. In [our latest experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378057/the-ask-question-wizard-is-now-in-testing), we found a 5.12% decrease in bad-quality questions, and a positive change in neutral-quality questions (2.26% increase) and good-quality questions (1.12% increase). We also saw an overall 3.42% decrease in overall question volume, which correlates pretty well with the decrease we saw in bad quality questions.

These early findings suggest that we're not only helping people ask better questions, but also stemming lower quality questions that occur on the site. These may seem like small percentages, but when we consider the scale that we're operating at with this launch, these small differences can have a large impact that we'll be looking for over the long term.

#### What's next?

One of the biggest wins with this launch is that we now have a framework for improving the question-asking experience. We wanted to get this first public version of guided mode out so we can continue improving on it as we learn more about how it's used. The team at Stack Overflow has a lot of exciting ideas about how we can improve the question-asking experience with this in place, but we also want to hear from you! Go and try out the wizard, and tell us what you think could be improved and what new ideas you're excited for us to explore.

You'll be hearing more from me and the rest of the team in coming weeks about the wizard and other features that are coming soon. We think this is one of the first big steps we can take to help both newcomers and veterans of the site collaborate better on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why was 111 chosen as the limit? I hope it is higher, say 1000, (or 1111, if you don't want to press more than one key), as getting 100 or even 500 rep on Stack Overflow is very easy.

Comment: @BhargavRao It's what we tested with during previous experiments, so we're keeping that here for the first release. As we learn more about how people are using this, we'll probably experiment with different thresholds and adjust if needed.

Comment: Interesting. What has this done to the traffic on software/hardware rec. and SU?

Comment: @Mysticial We'll see. It's one of the things we're monitoring over the next few weeks and in the long-term.

Comment: Although I just posted a bug and may have some more feedback coming, I want to make clear that this is ***super exciting awesome news***, and that I'm really thankful that this has *finally* come to fruition. Who knows, it might not make any perceptible difference, but at least we've tried. I should probably only speak for myself, but I'm going to go out on a limb and say that all of the veteran users really appreciate you and the team working hard to make this happen.

Comment: I really like how links to the other stack exchange sites go straight to their help center, where one of the first links is what the user can ask about there.

Comment: When I opened up the wizards page and saw the options. I was joking to myself that 3 of the options would tell the user to GTFO. I was mildly amused that I wasn't entirely wrong, it sends them to a different site. haha

Comment: I have the *ask question* tab opened with one question in draft, should I avoid refreshing? Should I store it somewhere before loosing everything?

Comment: Whenever I see percentages like this, I think 'but what are the confidence intervals? Do all those decimal places really mean anything?' :/ Guided mode does look more friendly for new users though (Bugzilla has a similar guided mode vs. non-guided mode).

Comment: @TemaniAfif You should have drafts saved automatically once you start typing your question body.

Comment: @ahiijny Good question! All these percentages are statistically significant from our latest experiment. We had over 100K people involved in the experiment when it was running, and we were able to converge on these results with >90% confidence.

Comment: I meant that I already have the draft using the old page, it will be kept in the new one?

Comment: [So where's the data?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378070/1079354)  I want to be able to audit this and actually do some determinations based on tag or technology.

Comment: Feature request-ish: it might be a good idea adding some more stuff to the tag guidance, **especially** to avoid [misuse of IDE tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561).

Comment: It has been a long time coming! I'm happy to finally see this out, and hope it would indeed help guide newcomers into more helpful questions and answers!

Comment:  so happy to see this finally go out, thanks for everyone's hard work on it, including the community 

Comment: Could the 111 threshold be because getting 100 rep for linking from another stack exchange site is possibly easy, and so the extra 11 points are to be really earned ?

Comment: @LoneWanderer: yes obviously. This is aimed at very new users, who typically start at 100 rep. It should be useful to guide them to a good experience, also prevents us getting deluged in bad questions from new users.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: if we want to make this scale, time to create a new review queue *'Downvoted questions which were asked using the Ask Question Wizard'*, so we can spot bugs/weaknesses.

Comment: 5% fewer closed (terrible unanswerable trash) questions is... not great, I would've expected a much higher percentage. Either the metrics aren't getting everything, or the testing group wasn't representative, or something... but I was hoping for double digits at least. If the 5% number is correct, we still have a problem.

Comment: @IanKemp Considering the number of questions asked per day, an 11.92% reduction in bad questions asked is pretty good. It's certainly better than no change and thus no improvement. Even if there's no additional gains beyond that rate, I'd call the wizard an ongoing success. Of course, further gains would be spectacular.

Comment: @smci Jeff Atwood's the wrong person to ask for improvements to the site; he doesn't work at SO anymore.

Comment: @IanKemp - The entirety of the review queues remove something in the range of 15% per day. So even at 5% you are looking at an automated system having the same effect as a third of the entire community moderation effort for closure.

Comment: I already see vast improvements in my tag. Thank you so much for this!

Comment: @TylerH: thanks, [didn't know](https://blog.codinghorror.com/farewell-stack-exchange/)

Comment: @IanKemp - It is far more efficient to automatically prevent the need for content removal than it is to have community members do the removal manually. That said, Stack Overflow has gone the tooling route as well, and I have tried to do my share to help with the tooling in order to remove content. In addition, far too often in the past have we had the misuse of tools in order to prevent or remove content. Overall, it is a complex problem, and attempting to minimize the complexity by saying that it isn't being done because of "welcoming" isn't fair to all the hard work from everyone involved.

Comment: @TravisJ Apologies - I didn't intend to denigrate the efforts that you, and many others, have put into creating tools to help with curating this site. My anger and frustration is directed at Stack Overflow the company, which has persistently and intentionally frustrated those curation efforts, as well as tarring curators with the "unwelcoming" brush. This wizard is a long-overdue step in the right direction from SO the company, but so much more is so desperately needed.

Comment: I read the title as "Ask a Wizard a Question", so I'm disappointed. I wanted to know where they get their hats. :(

Comment: @BhargavRao Maybe that was selected because it is when you will be able to answer protected questions **_if you gained an association bonus_**.

Comment: I'm so glad to get guidance on this.  I ask bad questions all the time on here nad I'm glad to get more structured help that goes beyond constantly wondering why my questions are 'bad'

Comment: Clippy is dead....  Long live Clippy.

Comment: @BhargavRao "getting 100 or even 500 rep on Stack Overflow is very easy". Maybe when you started using the site it was, but not any more. It's taken me about six years to reach over 1111 rep. Admittedly, I haven't been particularly active for about three years and at least half of that's been from editing questions and answers. What's easy for you isn't necessarily so for others.

Comment: Example question about web server settings to support UTF-8 belongs on serverfault.  Please migrate...

Comment: I think it might be a good idea to add an extra check besides the reputation threshold: have you asked a question before. If not then also show the guided mode, independent of rep.

Comment: Will this also be added to other sites too? I can see this being a good thing for Code Review.

Comment: I have a rep over 2K but I'll be using the guided mode for my next questions for a while.  Forever, if it works, once if it doesn't.

Comment: As a mod on a couple of sites, this really is great news!

Comment: Yikes!  I just tried this out - didn't submit my test question, obviously.  The guided interface is a VERY broken UX.  If it was a real question, I would simply give up on submitting it...and just leave SO - that's probably the 5% reduction you see right there.  I'm not a child that needs hand-holding.  Also, if you jump to Traditional from Guided after having started, you lose *all* of your work and have to start over!  It's a good idea for brand new software devs, but, IMO, needs significant changes/improvements before it is ready for use.

Comment: @AgiHammerthief - I agree that getting sufficient rep to do anything is hard (for those who think it is "easy," go create a new account and use it exclusively for a few months).  Frankly, lurking on any given SE site should slowly boost rep over time (e.g. 1 rep per day per site visited up to 10 rep across all SE).  Also, for SO, linking a GitHub account to the SE/SO account should provide at least sufficient rep to get beyond the new guided interface if their GitHub profile has been reasonably active for at least a year (factoring in number of commits, non-forked repos, issues, etc).

Comment: *"4. Describe expected and actual results"* is probably my favorite part. But all the "do" and "do not" examples are great!

Comment: Trivia: **Wikipedia** has that too.

Comment: good good good good

Comment: *you'll be able to switch to traditional mode* after *first answering a few questions* ...or by changing the URL to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?guided=false` if you're a tech nerd ... sorry, forgot where I was for a moment.

Comment: I really suggest to add this wizard to any user. The limit **is useless** since this new feature should help everyone to write better questions. Your reputation of 3k does not mean that you will write better question than a 1k users.

Comment: I'm not seeing the "Switch to Guided Mode" when I click Ask Question. I also think it would be awesome to have a guided mode for answering questions, since it's very demoralizing when you spend a lot of time asking a question and a new user comes and provides a one line irrelevant answer in order to get reputation points; which then leads to everyone else ignoring the question due to it having an answer.

Comment: Do we have any metrics yet for how many people are going through the wizard and are still being closed as off topic?

Comment: I can't find the "Use traditional mode" link, and I have 4122 reputation and I've answered lots of questions.

Comment: Feature request! or bug? When the user is NOT logged in visiting "stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard", they get "Page not found" page!  For a better UX, please detect this condition and display something friendlier!

Comment: @JonChan Does the wizard add `<pre></pre>` tags to code blocks?  I've noticed a large increase in questions that use those tags to format code ever since this was announced.

Comment: I just want to say, I've seen the new [unguided] Ask Question page for the first time today, and I think it's great. 

Comment: Why was this disabled? A link to a announcement is all I need.

Comment: @VScode_fanboy [Meta Stack Exchange - The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/241919) which linked to the blog post [Research update: Improving the question-asking experience](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/26/research-update-improving-the-question-asking-experience/) mentioning "*And following the success of the Ask Question Wizard—our guided ask question form for users with less than 111 reputation — we decided to take a step back and look for ways we could make a more unified, positive experience for everyone.*"

Answer (score 343):

Maybe it's just me, but I didn't even see the additional fields at first. I did what was asked of me in the blue highlight and then hit the blue button:

[image: Guided mode description next button skips other fields: background, show some code, etc]

I expected hitting Next  after filling in **Summarize the problem** would put me in the **Provide background including what you've already tried** and instead it brings me to review. This seems like an easy mistake to make.

Comment: It’s not just you. I’d expect next to take me to step 2 as well

Comment: No surprise this answer (concern) is top voted. No; not just you.

Comment: Perhaps "Next" could be programmed to take you to the next stage *unless* you've done them all, in which case it would take you to review...

Comment: @Nick That's more or less what I was expecting: if the last box is highlighted and you hit next that takes you to the review page: so you can skip a step, but you have to have to either click on it or click past it in the last: either way you have to actively skip it.

Comment: And the + icons should be a downwards arrow. + makes it seem like it's additional, a.k.a. non-essential, info to put in. The downward arrow shows it's a collapsed tab without implying it's an addendum.

Comment: Maybe they should have asked around the [UX SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) before implementing this one... :p

Comment: Agree this could be improved. We'll revisit this.

Comment: Same for me.... definitely force them to go through all the steps, even if they're not required to enter anything in 3 of them.

Comment: @lucasgcb Funny; I was about to post the same comment ...

Comment: @person27 I didn't not see those plus icons at all when I tried it

Answer (score 194):

#### Be more explicit in the homework warning

Currently, the effect of selecting the *homework* option in the first step appears to be that you get shown this:

[image: homework instructions]

I find this phrasing unnecessarily weak and giving a false impression to pure help vampires.
The tip suggests that asking a proper question “only” improves the quality and speed of answers.
It fails to mention that not adhering to this is extremely frowned upon, unethical, and will (or at least should) yield no answers whatsoever.

Also, “homework questions” is bound to be naïvely interpreted as referring to the homework task itself, which is exactly what we do not (directly) want to help with.

I would suggest a wording along the lines of the following:

> #### Great!
>
> Our community is here to help you with coding questions about your homework. We’ll take you through a step-by-step guide for writing a great question.
>
> > Tip: We will not do your entire homework for you, only help you with it. Show us your code and focus on a specific problem you're having. Tell us what you already understood and where you are struggling.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd even say "for writing a great question", as opposed to something like "for writing an answerable quesiton" or "for writing a question our users can answer".

Comment: @Tas Fair point, but that's the same description they use for all the other pages, so consistency dictates that it be kept. Also, welcoming wagon.

Comment: This is **excellent**!

Comment: I take issue (just a little bit) with the phrase "Our community is here to help you with...your homework."  That's *not* what this site is for.  It really needs to say "We can help you with questions about homework, *as long as you* <instructions to write a good question>."

Comment: +infinity for including "We will not do your entire homework for you."

Comment: I'd just say "We will not do your homework for you." Period. We answer programming questions that demonstrate the minimum threshold of competence necessary, not just _gimme teh codez_.

Comment: Also, "We’ll take you through a step-by-step guide for writing a great question"  has issues. #1: it misrepresents the wizard. The wizard builds the question; a step-by-step guide is a list of instructions. Perhaps "In the following steps, let's build your question." (Feels a little clunky. Massage as necessary.)

Comment: #2: it feels like a bit of a non-sequitur, particularly in the original text. The proposed text fixes this, I'd say. Here's my beef with the original: If you're offering to help me with my homework, I expect the last word of the sentence to be "answer": "We’ll take you through a step-by-step guide for writing a great... answer." I already have the question, you know? Again, just to be clear, I think Wrzlprmft's proposed text fixes this just fine: it makes the "question" in both sentences to be the one the asker is about to ask, not the one they're being asked in their homework assignment.

Comment: @MathieuK.: “We’ll take you through a step-by-step guide for writing a great question” is displayed for all cases where you are not directed to another site. I left it in, because I wanted to focus on one aspect only. Your criticism is best posted as another answer.

Comment: That's true. Your answer made me rethink the importance of it, though. Will delete.

Comment: I want to say I already saw a few mentions under copy-paste homework questions where the OP comment that they posted under the "homework section", and did not understand the downvotes/closure.

Comment: I think the proposed response is still too weak.  There needs to be some very specific warnings that homework questions unless crafted well often get a poor response.  Then we need to provide some better guidance on just how to write that question.  Maybe link to [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) but I'm sure there are even better resources

Comment: When dealing with people with low comprehension skills and/or non-native speakers we have to use the most basic and direct language. The kind of lingo that when translated online to, say, Russian and then back to English it has to keep making sense.

Comment: You might add:  "Know your course policies about seeking external help or posting course material on the internet before asking questions.  While you can delete unanswered questions that are down-voted, questions with up-voted answers remain visible to future viewers and can not be deleted."

Answer (score 143):

#### [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Guide users to create an MCVE

The guidance currently highlights the importance of code formatting (which is great!), but it fails to note the importance of creating a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

[image: Image of the 'share your code' section of the ask a question wizard]

Although the bold text (*'Share as little code as possible that still reproduces the same problem'*) starts to hint towards this, a new user would most likely interpret this as 'copy-paste the only section of my code that has a problem' - which is not correct, as such a sample would be neither complete nor verifiable. Additionally, I found that my eyes skimmed over the bold section, straight to the examples - it was only when I purposefully searched for a link to MCVE that I fully read the sentence.

An ideal solution would be to add another 'good' example, saying something like *'<tick> Create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example'*, and linking to the [relevant help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Agree. I've been reviewing new users posts for months now and almost all of them fails to add the steps and/or the code required to **reproduce the issue**. It is very tiresome to explain to them individually that we can't help them if we can't reproduce what they're facing. IMO it's the #1 cause of bad newcomers questions and I expected more details and warnings to be provided in the wizard.

Comment: @NinoFiliu Don't waste your time trying to squeeze blood from very dense stones, just downvote and move on.

Comment: @IanKemp thats a bleak outlook... Newcomers should be treated as such `new`. If you have the time to downvote, you have the time to write a small comment why. Otherwise IMO you're as much a detriment to the community as newcomers with bad questions. >> https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Newcomers are expected to read and follow extremely basic instructions; this wizard was necessary because they weren't willing to do even that much. The reason for those instructions **is so that we can help them solve their problem as fast as possible** - so by ignoring those instructions, they are actively sabotaging themselves! I don't know about you, but that sounds like the exact opposite of intelligent behaviour to me.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Pray tell where exactly does the CoC mandate that downvotes be explained? | Also keep in mind that people who actively curate the site cast many votes per day and there's a LOT of garbage flowing in all the time. Together they make up a fraction of a percent of the total userbase. Time is valueable and limited, and they do it for free. Frankly it doesn't seem reasonable to expect them to spend time reminding careless people to proof-read their gibberish before posting it. (Let alone explain to 10k rep users that they need a MCVE instead of 1 line ripped out of context)

Comment: @DanMašek I understand, I did add `IMO` as I do know It's not required. But I would rather you didn't curate if you don't have the time to explain votes. I just feel that we are pushing away users who could potentially grow into useful contributors by not helping them and  under `Our Expectations` it's broad but it does say `If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming.` and `Edits, comments, and suggestions are healthy parts of our community.` which `IMO` are broad ways of saying to help newcomers vs quickly downvoting and moving on.

Comment: @DanMašek It doesn't say it's mandated and 10K users vs First Time Posters are two different beasts completely.

Comment: Wait, do backticks work now!???!?

Comment: I agree that this should be improved! *"Don't paste an entire file"* What? Exactly the opposite is true: (1) Create an MCVE and then (2) paste the entire file (otherwise, it wouldn't be *complete*). In fact, users should *not* be encouraged to "share their code"! They should be guided to *create a new MCVE from scratch*, based on their code. (And yes, discouraging users who think this is too much work from completing and submitting their question is probably a good thing.) After that, a link "discard my question, I just solved it by trying to create an MCVE" might be a good addition, ...

Comment: ...so that we get statistics on how many people were helped by guiding them to create an MCVE.

Comment: I think the **Show some code** section covers _minimality_ and _verifiability_ but lacks of emphasizing _completeness_. In principle, the user only has to realize that another user wants to replicate his code and needs everything necessary to do so, such as example data and also additional packages. We could just extend the phrase a little. _"Share as little code as possible, that still produces the same problem, **including the data and non-base packages needed for reproduction.**"_ There's a sophisticated duplicate in the trash, unfortunately I overlooked this answer.

Comment: Sometimes one line is totally fine as a MCVE especially in a language like R where there are sample data sets available (and reproducing issues using one of them often leads to the solution for the issue).

Comment: @andrewtweber Yes, since a few months ago now. I could swear I stumbed on some kind of announcement, but I can't find it...

Comment: “Share the shortest code except that would allow somebody else to reproduce your issue.” // “Don't include anything that isn't needed to reproduce the issue.” // “If at all possible, provide code that can be run as presented.”

Comment: I now have to edit stuff again to add backticks.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei If your answers are using the other method of code formatting (4 spaces), then that's fine and will continue to work perfectly. There's no need to edit your answers to switch to the backticks method. You may just find it more convenient in the future to use the backticks method for new answers.

Comment: @andrewtweber here is the reference Pac0 was mentioning: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/184109/revisions

Answer (score 141):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The *Do any of these answer your question?* still appears when the search for similar questions returns 0 results, and asks you to verify that none of these 0 similar questions answer your question.

[image]

This issue has already been raised in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369689/7296893) when the prototype was just ready, and apparently is [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) there.

Comment: FWIW, probably any real question title will contain at least some words that will bring up some questions, even when they'll be completely irrelevant. Try e.g. "Why is my queldorf not florking?" OSLT.

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev Programming terms and utter nonsense are hard to distinguish sometimes, and real titles can return 0 results. For example, the title on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/195524/7296893) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9279295/7296893) both return 0 results, as do many other titles without any real words. These may be poor titles and it may not occur frequently, but it will certainly occur.

Comment: I was hoping this was [fixed already](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369689/4916627).

Comment: Guess we can('t) mark my answer as a duplicate. I'll leave it here as a signpost

Comment: @ErikA I think the point isn't that this step shouldn't appear when the title is gibberish; the point is that there's no point asking "do any of these questions help?" when the list of "these questions" is empty, because the answer will always be "no". Even if your title is excellent, if the system can't find anything that might be related, the "these things might be related" step can safely be skipped.

Answer (score 108):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The wizard **shakes violently** when loaded in Internet Explorer 11. This makes the wizard completely unusable in that browser and can cause accessibility issues with users with photosensitive epilepsy.

I've captured an animated GIF of the issue, but it's in spoiler markup because **epilepsy warning**:

> [image]

It seems that it cannot decide what the right width is, for responsive design. I did discover that reducing the width of the browser window works around the issue and makes it remain still.

Comment: If the goal of the new design is to reduce low quality questions. It would certainly help if it's hard to post one in the first place!

Comment: *when loaded in IE* - As Designed - WONTFIX.

Comment: Is the bug that it doesn't do this in all browsers?

Comment: @DavyM Not in Firefox at least. Reproducible here with IE, not with Firefox. Also only occurs on the _Tags_ page, which somehow is the first one with IE.

Comment: Really hate to say this @ErikA, but you missed the joke.

Comment: @Mysticial Naw, it'll just force them to go back to the traditional view and post their low-quality question there instead.

Comment: "It seems you are using an outdated or obsolete browser.  Are you sure you should be programming?"

Comment: Ahahaha, this is the most interesting IE-related bug I've seen yet! xD Thanks for the laugh

Comment: ... I wouldn't be able to reproduce this even if I wanted to, I just wouldn't have a clue how. To make this happen by accident is next level.

Comment: I'm pretty sure IE is not a supported browser anymore for SO.

Comment: @TylerH [It is still supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)...semi-supported, but nevertheless supported.

Comment: @gparyani Sounds like this might be a good instance of "Support may be dropped in the future, without notice, if new functionality is implemented that cannot be made to work in Internet Explorer 11" (not that there isn't a way to fix the shaking bug for IE11 but that it may not be worth their time).

Comment: @TylerH No no no, you've got it backwards!  HTML 6 will need to have a <shakeviolently> tag so that all the *other* browsers can support this feature in a standards-compliant manner.

Comment: This is a feature not a bug. Hopefully it will deter people from using IE.

Comment: Now also posted as https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382502

Comment: @BJ I'd bet that there's a good chance that IE users have more high quality questions and answers than the average SO user. Think about it: The majority of users using IE are working in some restricted corporate environment. Certainly not beginners wanting help with their home work. I doubt we have statistics for that, but it'd be interesting to see.

Comment: @gparyani Love the "epilepsy warning", and really good thinking of using spoiler markup.

Comment: But when the wizard starts shaking violently *and* shouts YOU SHALL NOT PASS, that's when you're in trouble

Comment: It seems that you are using IE, do you want to ask a question on [Experts Exchange](https://www.experts-exchange.com) instead?

Answer (score 87):

Some of my reactions...

---

"What type of question do you have?" has a number of gotcha selections to short circuit off topic questions.

Good.

I'd suggest adding "I have a question about this website" and redirect them here.

---

You can't navigate (back button) backwards through the wizard, and some courses of action don't have a previous button, such as choosing "Other" for type of question. There's a possibility if you go down one route and wish to go down another you have to start over from the beginning. Not what I'd expect. I'd expect the back button to work or for the previous button to be everywhere.

---

I still think asking for a title at the end is a better option than before writing the question, but placing the tags first is very good.

---

When showing the user questions that might already have my answer, don't show unanswered questions or questions that are downvoted. Sort by votes and pick the top 5. If you show fifteen hundred in random order like you're currently doing nobody's going to want to slog through that. Probably won't even bother checking one, I know I didn't feel like it.

---

Each step in the wizard has such a small initial edit size. I'd prefer a larger initial area, with a well defined bottom barrier that can be adjusted manually (as in the regular post box). Also, automatically collapsing previous sections when moving on will help save on scrollwheels.

---

If I don't put code blocks in the code section, consider this an error condition and prompt the user to format their code if they have not done so.

---

In the expected results section, prompt the user to add the full text of any error messages they were given.

---

I think overall you guys did a pretty good job on this, from what I've seen. Congrats.

Comment: Personally I tend to write/rewrite titles at the end so I do agree that's an effective order. That said, if we save that step for last, we've made them spend their time writing a question that there's an exact duplicate of. As long as our duplicate check is based on titles, titles probably need to come before the body.

Comment: Good point on that...

Comment: "*Sort by votes and pick the top 5*" - sorting by votes is only useful when I know that an old canonical question exists. Votes are not a good indicator of quality and relatedness, they vary too much because of different view counts. Potential duplicates should be ordered by relevance, [as they are today](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268318/1048572). (Of course, the algorithm can always be improved...)

Comment: @Catija Don't know whether this is good UI/UX, but would it be possible to show the title field before and after writing the question? Before writing the question, the title input could be labelled "Try to formulate a fitting title so we can search for similar questions already answered here. Don't worry, you can revise your title later" (or something like this). After writing the question, the user is asked to check whether they want to update their title, now that they've formulated the entire question.

Comment: @Catija Sorry, posted my comment too quickly - I just went through the entire assistant and saw that you can indeed change the title in the review section. So you can probably boil my idea down to mentioning that you can review the title (as well as tags and description) later.

Comment: Only showing *some* related questions improves the motivation to at least look at them.  How about showing five or ten and increase the list each time any of them actually got clicked upon?

Comment: "If I don't put code blocks in the code section, consider this an error condition and prompt the user to format their code if they have not done so." If I understand this correctly, you're making entering code mandatory. I disagree. Not every question *requires* code, such as [this one about `geth`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55431745/how-geth-estimategas-and-suggestgasprice-work). Recommending to the user that he/she enter relevant code and allowing this to be skipped would be better.

Comment: @AgiHammerthief no, I'm not saying adding code is mandatory. But if you use the code section and have no code format in it, consider that an error and warn the user that they should format their code. If you're not adding code there's not a real reason to use the section marked for code. If you use the section marked for code you should have some code in it.

Comment: I like some of these and would like to upvote them. Consider breaking into separate answers.

Answer (score 83):

#### [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) – Clarify that questions about *programming* software tools are on-topic

If I indicate that "I need to troubleshoot some software or hardware", the wizard assumes that I'm about to ask an off-topic question and attempts to redirect me to a more appropriate place (Super User).

That works well in *most* cases, and I appreciate the motivation behind it, but there is a very important exception. Per the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), one of the topics that can be asked about on Stack Overflow includes "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Practically speaking, that means questions about configuring your IDE, setting up a debugger, rebasing with Git, exiting Vim, and so on are allowed here. They might *also* be allowed on Super User, but that doesn't make them off-topic for Stack Overflow. Standing policy is that the asker should be allowed to choose where she wants to ask her question if it is on-topic for multiple sites. That decision is commonly based on where the asker thinks she will get the best answer, and in the case of programming tools, the best answer will almost certainly come from Stack Overflow.

You might say this is really not a big deal—why do we care if we redirect new askers to Super User?—but I disagree. There is plenty of confusion, even among long-time members, about whether questions about programming software tools are on topic. They *absolutely* are, and we need to be careful not to do anything that reinforces perceptions to the contrary.

Implementing this in a way that maintains the simplicity of the wizard is somewhat challenging, and I'd be open to suggestions about the best approach.

I don't think it makes sense to add another option button to the starting page of the wizard. It would look too similar to the existing ones, and too many options is actually a bad thing. So, I think we're going to have to modify/expand the existing option.

Maybe an interstitial step can be added that asks, *"Is your question about software tools used primarily by programmers?"* You can give an example or two (Visual Studio, Xcode, Git, Vim, etc.) in the body section. If the user clicks "Yes", they get routed to ask on Stack Overflow. If they click "No", they get routed to ask on Super User.

This would also allow later expansions to, *"Is your question about professional server or networking administration?"*, and routing to Server Fault. And other adjustments deemed necessary when the Super User folks start coming at us with pitchforks.

Comment: There's no confusion. The help center is clear. Being a question about a tool commonly used by programmers can be necessary but not enough to be a on topic question for Stack Overflow. It's also necessary to be a practical question unique to software development. That you want emacs to have the background of the album Led Zeppelin IV isn't unique to software development. Also, personally, I've found those questions to be better answered by SU,SF,AU,U&L than SO, so it's a win for most interested parties (asker and future readers).

Comment: Weird argument, @Braiam - the whole premise of the wizard is that the help center *isn't* sufficient for a good many new askers. Seems like offering a decision tree to help folks make the right call here would be a useful thing to have, particularly given past blow-ups when it comes to sites like Server Fault getting questions about the use of tools in dev environments where they very much should be on SO and probably aren't going to be answered well *anywhere else*...

Comment: @Shog9 I see every tool, as an extension of the help center. Stuff to make what the help center establish as the basis of interactions with the site and other users easy and smoothly. In this specific case, the overwhelming majority of the questions that would follow this pathway, don't need a eject button. What we need is that whatever information we provide after they arrive to the other side should confirm the expectations the guided tool set. I have a bug to report about that. Landing on site.se/help isn't very useful. A landing page may be necessary (migration could use it too?).

Comment: Can confirm widespread misconceptions about this being on-/off-topic.

Comment: @Braiam A question being about a tool commonly used by programmers may not be a sufficient condition for it to be on-topic, but it's also clearly not a sufficient condition for it to be *off*-topic, either, which is what the wizard currently presumes and what Cody is objecting to.

Comment: ... although I wonder if the even bigger problem with the redirect to Super User is that it doesn't indicate that the "software" you're trying to "troubleshoot" should be something publicly available rather than your own proprietary code that you're trying to debug. I would not be surprised if the SU community turn up here soon to ask us why the F they've got a pile of PHP debugging questions on their doorstep from askers who say they were sent there from Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MarkAmery I didn't say otherwise, but remember, people that has problem with their code would very rarely say that they have problem with a program but with their code. My gripping with Cody's answer is that tries to take something that has been very clear and muddy it, instead of improving the experience of the users that would be presented the tool. I told Shog what I believe is a bigger problem, and presented [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381690) also stating so. What would you believe is a bigger problem related to the wizard?

Answer (score 71):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) - Typo in the "Show some code" help text of the description step.

[image]

"Higlight" should be "Highlight".

Comment: Damn, noticed this and thought I was all slick.

Comment: @WilliamJones you were all slick.

Comment: lol nice spotting this

Answer (score 42):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Finally, we got tags before title. Can the search also be modified to include the tags in the "There may be similar questions"?

At present, even with guided mode, I still feel the similar questions list to be less than ideal.

### **[Include the chosen tags in the search criteria for "Questions that may already have your answer."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280668/include-the-chosen-tags-in-the-search-criteria-for-questions-that-may-already-h)**

An easy way to reproduce this is to, first: enter [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) as the tag; second, enter "how to sort an array"; third, look at the suggested similar questions.

I think that this is planned since I ask about it all the time, but just as a reminder :) *please include the tags in the search*.

---

Beyond that... so excited. This seems like a really beneficial tool for so many new users. I hope it pans out, and will take any amount of improvement. That said, there is a lot of potential here, even small percents will be large progress.

Comment: Personally I prefer the tags to be added after typing out the post body itself.  Writing the post often helps me to focus my thoughts and to determine what tags should be used.  I'd still be fine with them coming before the title, as long as the title is after the body (which also might now be a bad idea).

Answer (score 38):

#### [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) – Page title disappears as I click through the wizard

The `<title>` tag in the HTML is empty as I click through the wizard, which means that I get the raw URL appearing in my browser's title bar.

The title seems to be in place when I first open the page, but as I navigate through it, the `<title>` tag's contents somehow get cleared.

It might be *nice* to have the `<title>` dynamically update to reflect which step of the wizard I'm currently on, but that's a whole lot less important than just making sure that the page has a proper title. Keeping the original "Ask a Question - Stack Overflow" visible at all times would be acceptable.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me at present. I'm on Chrome on Windows.

Comment: Still broken in the initial step, "Type", @Mathieu.

Comment: True, the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard page. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?guided=true seems to be fine.) Sorry.

Answer (score 36):

#### [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Track the impact on the other sites redirected to by the wizard.

Since the wizard redirects askers to some other Stack Exchange sites, I would suggest to somehow track how this works, in order to make sure that we understand the impact. Staying oblivious of this impact carries a risk that affected sites may eventually push for their removal from wizard targets as was [discussed e.g. here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369772/839601).

<sub>Ideally we would want to know how many askers registered at the target site, how many of them asked a question, and how well this question went. But for a start, we could at least track amount of clicks from wizard to other sites (possibly sampled), similarly to how it is done for [hot questions at sidebar](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6304786#6304786).</sub>

Comment: related matters are also discussed in [another answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381690/839601)

Answer (score 36):

I put in the python tag, and then asked the question "how do I convert an integer to a string". The top non-duplicate answer was for Java. I would expect the tag I entered be used to filter the other possible answers.

[image: Screenshot of the suggested duplicate list, showing that the tag is clearly not used]

Comment: You are [not the only one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381698) to request this feature :-)

Answer (score 32):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

I think that telling the users to not worry can be setting them up for failure.

> "And don’t worry—you can edit your question after it’s posted, too."

While it is true that the OP can edit their question once posted, community voting and actions are intended to be reflective of the post in its current shape, and if the current post looks something like this:

[image]

Then I am concerned that the user will have a rough go of things. Including the nod towards editing is good, but instead of "Don't worry", **there should be a warning that voting and actions will be immediate and will be reflective of the post in its current shape**, perhaps also including that asking a question at Stack Overflow expects a good amount of research to have been done up front, since at this point most of the basic questions have been asked.

Comment: Absolutely. People not worrying about what they post is IMHO one of the main causes of the issues we're facing.

Comment: "500 people will read this question in the next three minutes. Are you sure this is how you want it to look?"  (from my comment [the last time you raised this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369725/3614835); others suggested using the number of tag watchers, and suggesting the user stick around to edit in response to comments)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: I like the sentiment, but "500" is a strong exaggeration (probably two orders of magnitude, in fact). Most questions never reach 500 views at all. I ran a sampling of 16k questions over most of a day with a quick PS script and got [this CSV of views after 15 minutes](https://www.tuggycomputer.com/nathan/SO15MinuteQuestionViews.csv). 99.9% of questions get 36 or fewer views in their first 15 minutes. 90.8% get 13 or fewer. 54.9% get 5 or fewer. I'm collecting data for a 3-minute examination as well, just in case that's interesting.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - It is good to get real data in the hopes of quantifying how many people actually view these questions, perhaps 500 is a bit of a stretch. I think that looking at 2 days worth of questions may be a little bit too small of a sample size though. Also to note, many users view titles and abstracts from the question list without actually viewing the question itself. I think something like "dozens of users" would be easily appropriate.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you intend to choose an example where the expected output matched the actual output _already_?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - There are many problems with this example question :)

Answer (score 31):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

### Logged-out users get a 404 error when trying to access the wizard

When users who are logged out attempt to follow the link to the wizard, they receive a 404 error. The wizard link only seems to work for users signed into an account.

I understand that Stack Overflow (unlike most other SE sites) doesn't allow anonymous users to ask questions, but the normal "Ask" page shows a nice error message indicating that the user must be logged in. However, the Wizard link shows a 404 error, which has caused users to [get confused](https://twitter.com/coderlibre/status/1109223233868492805).

Can we please make the Wizard link also show the same nice error, indicating that the user must be logged in?

Answer (score 30):

#### [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Don't allow users to go to the Review tab if the other areas haven't been completed

It's easy to leapfrog the **Tags**, **Title**, and **Description** tabs and head straight to the **Review** tab without entering anything on them, with the big, blue **Post Your Question** button enabled. Leaving any of these fields blank prevents the question from being submitted and raises errors to the user, but why even show this page until they've successfully completed the first three tabs?

If the goal is to "provide structured guidance to newcomers", then force them to do the first parts of the wizard, and only bring them to the review when they've done so. As it stand now, it's easily avoided.

Comment: Your suggestion would be a good way to help with the issue mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381678/7795130) too.

Comment: What value does it add to impede movement through question editing?  This was the first feature I checked for and was very relieved it didn't restrict my movement.

Comment: @sk8forether My FR has nothing to do with question editing. It has to do with allowing the user to skip past the important parts of the wizard and end up at the Review tab before they've completed what's been asked for.

Comment: @j08691 It seems completely reasonable to me to want to review your question throughout editing.  Perhaps what you are really suggesting is not being able to _submit_ a question before all sections are complete?  I'm not sure I agree with that either, but it makes more sense to me than impeding movement.

Answer (score 28):

#### Tag warnings are weird now

How to reproduce:

1. Ask a question tagged [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex).
2. Go through the entire wizard.
3. In the final step, note the tag warning at the bottom:

   [image: tag warning for regular expressions]

The problems with this is that this warning was made for the traditional mode, where it is fine as it is ([if it gets actually shown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278399/255554)).
However, in the question wizard some of this is out of place:

- Advice about other or more specific tags is best given on the tag page.
- Reminders what questions are completely off-topic is also best given on the tag page or shortly afterwards (see the tag warning for [seo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo) for an example).
- Some advice is obsolete as the wizard already incorporates it by default, e.g., as “show some code” or “describe expected and actual results”.
- Some advice should be given before the question is fleshed out, e.g., the advice about including both, matching and non-matching examples in the above tag warning.

The probably easiest solution would be to split the bullet points in the tag warning into a handful of categories like:

- Show after selecting tags.
- Show before writing question.
- Show at the end.
- Don’t show in question wizard.

Then, show them according to their category in the wizard, and combine them in the traditional mode (like it is now).

Answer (score 21):

#### [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) – "Discard" should redirect to the beginning of the wizard

When you go to the "Review" page and click on *"Discard"*, you should be redirected to the **beginning of the guided tour**. Currently, only all form fields are cleared but you stay on the current page.

Answer (score 21):

There is still one aspect of this that is pretty unapproachable to new users.

## Why in the world is there no formatting toolbar?

We get one in the normal asking/answering boxes, and it is much more user-friendly (though it still allows the exact same help that the guided mode does if you want to click the <kbd>?</kbd> button and learn more.

Answer (score 20):

I've commented on this proposal at every iteration, and I guess I'll once again register my dissent, although it feels pointless now. While this feature has improved since [last iteration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378057/1709587), I still disagree with its existence.

Most good questions on the site couldn't've been asked using Guided Mode. My posts are consistently well received, but I'm not sure if I've *ever* asked or answered a question that fit the 4-part structure guided mode asks for, and many of them couldn't possibly be contorted into it without damaging the question.

I don't really care if we have statistics showing an improvement in question quality if that improvement amounts to making what would've been bad debugging questions merely mediocre. I want us to get thoughtfully-crafted, widely-applicable questions that provide value to future readers. Guided mode is at best an irrelevance to that goal. The only "good" thing it can do is help thoroughly incompetent askers - people who are here to get their broken code debugged and who cannot even manage to coherently and answerably ask for that help if presented with an empty text box - to post better-polished turds. For what? How does that make us a better library of knowledge? Why does anyone *care*?

I guess my side has lost the debate; the comments and votes here make clear that the community seems to be enthusiastic about this feature. But I still want to say, one more time, to all of you: I think your enthusiasm is misguided. You will not get interesting questions that hold the attention of experts and produce value to future readers from this form. And, even with the option to swap to traditional mode, the signals about what questions are allowed here - like the form that only really supports debugging questions, or the instruction in the "Other" flow that only questions containing source code are acceptable - will drive away intelligent, conscientious contributors who would've asked thoughtful, broadly applicable questions if only we hadn't put up signs telling them that their contributions were unwelcome.

Which is a loss for us.

Comment: I'm...at odds with how to respond to this feedback.  On one hand, yes, it does pigeonhole askers into a more guided way of asking a question, and that can lead to situations where some askers will be driven away due to the messaging we have for new users.  On the other, we're starting to stem the tide of crap flowing in, something that's sorely needed.  I guess the question is, what's more important?  Potential askers not asking due to messaging?  Or curators sorely needing a break from the flood?  It seems to be six of one, and half a dozen of another.

Comment: @fbueckert:  Curators don't need a "break" from the flood.  They need a dam.  If a feature like this can only prove that this is providing a break, what would happen next?

Comment: To your point about statistics, Mark - if we have something objectively measurable, then we can go *back* to the PMs and identify the pain points of the site in terms they can understand.  Nobody wants to expend development resources for marginal gain, and I get the impression that their numbers would hold a better conversation than either of us.

Comment: In my opinion, this analysis is looking on the wrong side of the issue. You are examining questions which are posted by using this feature. First, those questions would have been posted anyway, so I disagree that improving them in any fashion is a loss. Second, and most important, this feature aims at preventing questions which should not have been posted by showing at least somewhat of a framework that needs to be completed in order to ask. Any percent gain of prevention by forcing users to at least consider the amount of work necessary to post will be beneficial.

Comment: @Makoto Do we need a dam?  Sure.  I just don't think the Ask Question wizard is one, so I'm comparing what I see as the two potential scenarios.

Comment: @fbueckert:  I don't think [we can objectively prove one way or the other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381794/1079354) if it is a dam or not.  I don't think it is either, honestly, but if you're expressing those as goals, we should be able to verify one over the other.

Comment: @Makoto No issues there.  Auditable data is a must to see how much of an impact it's having.  It's just my opinion that a ~12% decrease in low quality doesn't do much but extend the period until curators burn out.

Comment: Asking thoughtful, widely-applicable questions isn't something you can make happen with some handholding, nor is it a common occurrence (otherwise "great" would be "mediocre"). I think this concern should be focused on ways the wizard *prevents* such questions from being asked rather than complaining that the wizard doesn't "encourage" such questions. Or perhaps your concerns should be addressed to primary/secondary school teachers across the globe who can do something about peoples' ability to think critically/at a high intellectual level, rather than here, far too far down the road.

Comment: Mark, although I missed participating in the previous discussions, I'm very sympathetic to your concerns. I understand that with a wizard like this, we are essentially optimizing for passable "debug my code" questions. On the other hand, experience tells us that giving people a blank textbox and expecting them to draft a coherent question is *not* likely to be successful. And since "debug my code" is the most common type of questions from beginners, a bit of hand-holding to improve their quality seems like a reasonable first step. Our library of knowledge is becoming a dumping ground.

Comment: I agree with Cody. I think this is a case of it being the lesser of two evils.

Comment: @TravisJ The feature may *aim* at preventing questions that should not have been posted, but it actually prevents *anything* that isn't a debugging question. Your view that anything that reduces the amount of bad questions must be good is blinkered, and exactly what I'm attacking. When a magical river of sewage and diamonds is running into your garden, and someone puts up a sign that says "Please refine your sewage before pouring; also, no diamond throwing", you don't accept the sign did good because it caused a 5% reduction in raw sewage. The sewage is unimportant. *What about the diamonds?*

Comment: @MarkAmery - What a great analogy. So, in this magical river, there is 99.999% sewage, and randomly a diamond is somehow attached to an earring somewhere floating near the bottom. The sewage contains all sorts of filth, sometimes even dead animals. All this does is put in a very generous filter to only catch the dead animals. The earring will never hit it. If a user is highly proficient in asking and technical writing, they will switch out of guided mode.

Comment: @TravisJ Our core disagreement then is perhaps not one of values but one of predictions. I expect the diamond earrings to get caught in the filter *all the time* - in fact, for the filter to extract a much bigger percentage of all the earrings than it does of the sewage. The trouble is that I expect skilled writers with interesting questions to disproportionately be conscientious, rule-following people. And I expect such people to be deterred when we present them with a wizard with instructions that suggest that their question doesn't belong, even if we don't outright block them.

Comment: @TravisJ Note that to even get the option of switching out of guided mode, the user needs to have already selected a category and seen the guidance about it. For anything other than a homework problem or a question "about some code", it will tell them that they should only continue asking their question if it includes code. Plenty of good questions do not include code, but law-abiding new askers who want to ask them will be presented with instructions to not do so. That, I expect, will do more harm to us than a 5% sewage reduction does good.

Comment: My opinion on this isn't quite as strong as Mark's, but I've started to see questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55369692/what-is-an-algorithm-that-checks-if-a-word-is-a-palindrome) that *clearly* went through the wizard, and may have become *worse* as a result.

Comment: Came here to agree with this. I just starting posting a question and I felt that guided mode was horrible and awkward. I had a [question that was downvoted to -15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233124/addition-method-to-java-class) and honestly I don't think this would have helped at all. I guess this design decision killed a lot of my faith in SO, if things really are that bad. I miss the days when the site was more like a wiki, a form of crowdsourced documentation.

Answer (score 20):

One thing that bothers me about the new wizard is that Stack Overflow was originally something of an attempt to collaboratively build an FAQ; the ideal was that people who had a question about programming wouldn't have to ask it on Stack Overflow, because the question would already be there, and the answer would already be there, thus there'd be no need to post a duplicate.

The emphasis on "show your code" in the new question wizard means that generic questions whose answers would benefit everyone are now more or less impossible to post. Let's take [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/266704), which I selected semi-arbitrarily, as an example; I'd consider it a good example of an FAQ-style question which is likely to be of benefit to any reader which has a question about weak references in JavaScript. Now imagine a new user trying to post a good, ontopic, generally useful question like that one using the new question wizard.

Their first step is to list their type of question, and they already get stuck: it's not a question about code, it's not a homework problem, it's not asking for a recommendation, it's not a troubleshooting issue. So they have to choose "Other". Now for the question to be appropriate to SO, it needs to "include a bit of code", "concern a specific coding issue, algorithm, or language", "not be opinion-based". The second and third categories definitely fit. The first doesn't. Is this an "and" or an "or"? The page doesn't use a conjunction. Treating it as an "and" quickly reaches a dead end (even though it looks like one!), so let's assume our user decides to treat it as an "or" and continues asking on Stack Overflow.

The next step is tags (OK, [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [weak-references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak-references), that's easy). Step after that is title; "Does JavaScript have weak references?" seems like a reasonable title. Then comes the duplicate check, and there are no duplicates listed. (Of course, because I'm using an existing question as an example for this thought experiment, there actually *is* a duplicate! But the duplicate check doesn't find it simply from the tags and title. That shouldn't be much of a surprise; the text of the post is the most helpful part for duplicate-searching, so the duplicate search and post-writing pretty much have to happen in parallel, like they do with the old workflow.)

Our hypothetical user, now that they think there are no duplicates, starts trying to write the text of the post, and everything starts falling apart:

1. Summarize the problem
2. Provide background including what you've already tried
3. Show some code
4. Describe expected and actual results

How many of these points fit? 1 sort-of, 2 and 4 very tenuously, 3 not at all. It's not possible to write this question using the template used by the new wizard, because it's a generic question describing a generic issue, and which gains as a result of that. The template is basically trying to force Stack questions posts to look like a "debug my code for me" or "help me finish my unfinished code" question. Now, it's pretty good at making those sorts of questions provide the information they need for people to solve them; but it's immediately repelling any other sort of question, including the fundamental questions that Stack Overflow derives most of its value from. Most frequently-asked-questions won't have a corresponding frequently-given-code-sample to go with them!

The fix to this would probably be to add an extra path through the wizard, but I'm not immediately sure what it would look like or what sort of information it would need to aim for.

Comment: To note, if this had considered tags in the search, then the duplicate would have been found. [Please support the request to include tags in the similar questions search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381698/1026459).

Comment: "it's immediately repelling any other sort of question, including the fundamental questions that Stack Overflow derives most of its value from"... this has been a troubling trend for a while now in my opinion, but it is also just an effect of the way that building this type of knowledge base has. See some analysis on that here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374083/1026459

Answer (score 20):

The context of the section prompts are lost between the form and the final question.

What would it look like if you inserted the actual headers into the resulting question? (The author still has the opportunity to edit them out on the last page.)

Or take it a big step further (maybe too big for the legacy of SO), and maintain these four pieces of content as separate attributes on a question throughout, for formatting, searching, etc.

For example, in the Q/A format, this seems reasonable:

[image]

But without the context of the headers, the question is murky:

[image]

Comment: Yep! I never repeat prompts that are provided for me. It's actually a common mark of inexperience as a writer.

Answer (score 18):

Okay, I'll make my position official.

Until I (as a layman) can see any queryable data as a result of users using this campaign, **I will condemn this feature**.

The percentages given aren't as amazing as I would want them to be; e.g. 5% overall doesn't compare with an unknown percentage of improvement or regression in our worst tags (PHP, JavaScript, C#, Java).

Until we can audit the data for ourselves to see how well this is going, I'm just flat-out refusing to agree that this wizard is actively helping users ask better questions **because we have no way to prove it**.

I will promise this much:

**Once metrics are provided for querying, I will willfully withdraw my condemnation.**
I want to use the metrics as a means of conversation and improvement, by asking what could be done to improve in certain tags, or what isn't working based on feedback from a denizen of a high-traffic tag.

Comment: Abstaining on a feature's merits is not that big of a deal, but that's very different from "condeming this feature" in boldface, which is a much bigger deal and a rather destructive criticism. This would be much better received, I think, if it were worded simply as a request for access to query-able data. Personally I don't think it's something worth querying, but I'd support people having access to the data if they wanted it. I can't support this kind of rude complaint, however.

Comment: @TylerH:  I find it less "rude" and more "pointed".  [I put this request in back in December](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378070/1079354) when they were first discussing it, and we've heard crickets about it since.  I'm stating that I have no way to trust that this is making the site a better place or making questions any better because we don't have any actual statistics to prove one way or another, in spite of what the desired outcome is.

Comment: @TylerH:  They've run this trial *since* about December when they first put it into a beta of sorts, and we've not had any auditable statistics about this, either.  We just have the number of 1-5% of improvements.  **This doesn't tell us much.**  This doesn't say across what tags, across what technologies, or if there was a higher-than-average (or worse-than-average) trend in the hostly contested and most notorious tags on the site.

Comment: @TylerH:  If a feature comes out claiming to improve something, it should be backed up with *some* evidence.  Until we can see that evidence, I have no reason to believe the claims.  That's really all I'm stating here.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me why you're taking such an obstinate stance on this. While I agree it'd be nice to see the data, why does the fact that no data has been published make you *against* the feature? Do you think the team is lying to us here? Is it not worth trying anyway? I mean, you kinda have to *try* something before you can generate meaningful data anyway. A small-scale test is really only to shake the bugs out of the wizard, not to provide representative data on which to draw meaningful conclusions.

Comment: I wanted to see [if there were any takeaways from the last time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373160/1079354) that a feature like this was released, @CodyGray.  I've been [skeptically optimistic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1079354+wizard) about if this feature would work at all, and at least in internal testing they said, "It did".  Now I watch Java every day.  I still see some of the same old poor questions in Java today as I did when this was still in Beta.  I want some kind of *proof* that this is going to really work.  I'm just left with trusting their word.

Comment: @CodyGray:  If nothing else, I hope this serves as an attention-grabber.  If you're going to say that something is measurably and demonstratively better, [then transparency is paramount](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378057/the-ask-question-wizard-is-now-in-testing/378070#comment657900_378070).  Without that transparency, we really don't have anything good to go off of.  I mean, I can only look at what Java questions were posted today, y'know.  I can't say one way or another if this is actually *working* without any way to see the data.

Comment: Okay, so...what's your counter-proposal? What should we try instead?

Comment: @CodyGray:  All they really need to do is make the metrics they're using publicly accessible.  They're internal now, as far as I know it, but they exist in some form.  Allowing us to query them to actually see how well they work for specific tags - not *just* the overall picture - would be more than enough to placate me.

Comment: @Makoto What makes you think that user was even prompted with the wizard? They have ~240 rep more than is needed to not be prompted with it by default.

Comment: @TylerH:  Yeah, ya caught me.  That was a rant.  I'll withdraw that complaint.

Comment: @Makoto The evidence they gave is the metric/statistics they provided (e.g. the delta of questions of various descriptions). It's not reproducible evidence in that you can't run the numbers from the data yourself, but it's still evidence. For comparison, what other per-user preferences do we have access to via SEDE?

Comment: @TylerH:  To *that* point, none of the existing per-user preferences to date actually impact the quality of questions we get on the site.  If you're talking about things like who follows tags or who has the top bar stickied, those aren't material in a discussion around question quality.  If we're supposed to have information about this actually *helping* improve question quality, having this be reproducible is kinda important.  5% may come from some subset of the site overall but it could be a negative value depending on what you look at.  We don't really *know*.

Comment: It is easily possible to have a strong effect on quality by limiting the lowest quality questions from even being posted. This is part of what the mentorship program accomplished. There are statistics to back that up as well. Once users realize they need to have some sort of structure for their post, then often end up rethinking if they should ask...

Comment: ...Uncertainty leads to questions never being posted, which saves the community a whole heap of time and reduces the amount of low quality entering the system. The entire review system retroactively removes something like 10-15% of these from happening. By relation, 5% would be massive.

Comment: @TravisJ:  I agree in large part with your assertion, but that's not 5% *per tag*.  If we got 5% less Java or PHP questions that would be a win.  But I have no way to prove if that's the case.

Comment: @Makoto I disagree on both fronts; my ability to use custom question lists lets me sort for low (and high) quality questions to close/delete (or answer) better than I otherwise could. That's a pretty direct impact in my opinion, although it's a lagging indicator rather than a leading one. The same goes for tag watching and ignoring. Can you see what tags I'm watching? Or whether I get notifications on activity in those tags? As for the other front, what makes an impact to the quality of questions something that mandates data availability via SEDE?

Comment: Once there is data from this initial experiment (and perhaps their original A/B tests already have this) it should be trivial to see what the percent difference for abdonment was between users who started the classic ask question page (and who filled out at least the title or something to screen for users entering without typing) versus who started the wizard.

Comment: @TravisJ:  And *all* I'm asking for is that data to be made freely available already.  Otherwise, I see this effort as largely fruitless.

Comment: @TylerH:  No, I don't really need to know what tags you're individually watching, since it doesn't prove that you're asking questions in those tags, or a good contributor in those tags, or anything else.  How you choose to shape and view the content of the site is a personal decision, not tied to any metric of whether or not one is capable of asking a measurably good question.

Comment: @Makoto Whether I use the wizard or not is also not a direct indicator of a good question. What matters is the reception to those questions down the road. So when we introduce some features like tag watching, the quality of the site goes up, because it's easier to find stuff worth your attention, whether that's answering, editing, or closing. This wizard is just another way for the quality of the site to go up. As for asking a measurably good question, the wizard doesn't make that happen, it just prevents users incapable of doing it from asking at all.

Comment: @TylerH:  Um...I'm not sure if you missed that part of the announcement, but they're *directly* measuring question quality as part of this wizard.  Let's pause for a second to make sure we're on the same page here.

Comment: @Makoto I'm not sure what you're not sure about. At any rate, *my* point is they gave evidence, just not the level of access to the underlying data that you want, and your answer & its phrasing in condemning the feature is nonconstructive/nonsensical (it's rude [or 'pointed'] and you're willing to rescind your condemnation with access to data ?regardless of what the data shows?), premature (you haven't seen the data to make a meaningful conclusion to know whether it's worth condemning; see also: nonsensical), and contradictory (you say the data is good, you just want more, so why condemn it?)

Comment: @Makoto I agree with both you and TylerH here.  I would like to point out that, your feelings being what they may, your answer is here to represent your feelings and those of voters upon your answer.  I think that the language you use is actually counterproductive to your own goals, since something softer would actually receive at least one more upvote (mine) and thereby attract the attention of the powers that be.  Please, so that I and others can actually agree with you, edit your answer to be in the form of a request, rather than a demand.

Comment: @TylerH, I think that the argument here has become somewhat muddled.  Perhaps if we focus on improving the language of the post, we can achieve something?

Comment: @Scott:  I'm fine with the way I stated this.  The people who have thus expressed their support so far are doing so in spite of (or because of) my language or tone.  I respect that not everyone *approves* of it or agrees with it, but I don't feel it appropriate or prudent to weaken my tone because, in all honesty, this *really does* represent my feelings - **you cannot claim to have a feature which measurably improves quality without any metrics.**  If you don't wish to agree *because* of my tone, then I respect that decision too.

Comment: @Makoto, sometimes, expression of one's feelings is only a means to an end.  I think if you carefully consider your position on this matter, you will see that "expressing your feelings" was not your end goal, but that what you actually wanted was "obtaining access to the data."  Thus, it is prudent to carefully construct our statements not to express our feelings as accurately as possible, but to communicate a need to the community as effectively as possible.  If I have misread this situation, please carry on.

Answer (score 17):

This is a very minor gripe, but there's currently no way to use the stack snippet generator thing. I'm not sure that new users would discover that feature anyways, but I certainly missed it when I was trying to test out the wizard.

It might be useful to point out its existence if users select [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), or [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

Comment: Related on older discussions: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369792), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369995), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378179): currently, the formatting toolbar (and to the extent of markdown shortcut) is available only on the "Review" step.

Answer (score 16):

#### [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) – The wizard is not correctly implemented on mobile.

Steps to re-create:

1. Open Stack Overflow on a mobile browser in the mobile view of the page. (If you request the full site manually, you won't hit the error)
2. Click "Ask Question" on an account with less than 111 rep, or use the wizard link from this question (I tried both). The view will be changed to that of the full site, but the wizard will appear.
3. Select "I have a question about some code" and click "next" twice.

Instead of being taken to the next step in the wizard, the normal mobile traditional view appears, even though the URL is `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?guided=true&__=940538704` (Note the `guided=true` in the url).

[image: Traditional Mobile View]

In order to return to the wizard, a mobile user must scroll down to the bottom of the page and request the full site.

This could be considered a loophole for users to evade the wizard (I tried it on a brand new account and yes, I could bring up the normal Ask Question mobile view). Even if we don't care about users getting around the wizard in that way, it's still a very uncomfortable change to be forced into the full site view to use the wizard, dropped back into the mobile view without warning, and have to manually re-enable the full site view to continue with the wizard if you so desire.

Comment: I've had to do this in Brave to get anything at all to display properly.  What browser were you using?  I think this may just be a broader mobile display problem.

Comment: @Makoto Chrome for Android, 73.0.3683.75.

Answer (score 16):

## [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) Neeeeeed a better page title:

Without the wizard, the page title is:

> Ask a Question - Stack Overflow

With the wizard, the page title is as short as:

> [image]

No title! This makes my browser (Chrome) fall back to page URL:

> [image]

This is... not a good UX setting. Must fixxxxxx.

Comment: I think Cody's already covered this in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381672)

Comment: On the plus side, nifty browser theme.

Comment: If by "nifty" you mean, "difficult to read" then yes I agree :P

Answer (score 14):

The navigation needs an improvement.  *Every* <kbd>next</kbd> button should lead somewhere where I also find a <kbd>back</kbd> button to return.  Unfortunately, also the browser's back-button (or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>) doesn't work as expected and only restarts the whole wizard.

Things like these quickly create frustration.

When ever a <kbd>back</kbd> button on the target page is not possible (at least not in the current implementation), I suggest to change the <kbd>next</kbd> button on the origin page to something which makes it clear that this is a one-way path, e. g. by renaming it to <kbd>leave wizard and launch editor</kbd> or similar.

Comment: The fastest improvement I can think of is to open links which lack a back button (and are thus outside of the wizard) in a different window or tab.  This shouldn't be the final implementation of course, but it could quickly reduce stress for any tester.

Answer (score 14):

While selecting tags, the wizard is allowing me to type tags (seems like it is allowing the creation of new tags).

It should not allow me to type random tags in this step, in the final step it blocks me from adding new tags. It tells me that it requires 1500 reputation to create new tags.

[image: See this]
[image: See this]

Answer (score 12):

In the "Show some code" section, why not just automatically make that a code block instead of asking the user to provide the backticks?
I guess you could put context e.g. ``` csharp.

I think it would have been more user friendly if the wizard automatically did it.

[image]

Comment: The wizard should also offer four space indentation as a method for code blocks since it's the original method and one that most users are probably familiar with.

Comment: I have been on stack overflow for years. Admittedly, english is not my first language, but this is the first time I've ever heard the words backticks and tildes. I can guess, based on the examples though. Also, yes four spaces is what I've always used, and I was not aware that this was an option. I love the rest of the guide.

Comment: Related other answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382522

Answer (score 10):

I find unhelpful that people that would ask off topic questions on this site (after not reading the little /help/on-topic page) would find being dropped into site.se/help with a tons of links and no clear path forward. Maybe we need a /help/landing-from-so on those sites with a very short introduction of the site topic (what questions should be asked and not be asked (depending on the site that redirected them there?)) and a pathway for searching for answers/asking their question.

Comment: A link to [help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) would be most appropriate in my opionion

Comment: [also related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381697/839601): "Track the impact on the other sites redirected to by wizard..."

Comment: I'm a big fan of this idea.  Get some of [this guidance](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7182/what-goes-on-software-engineering-previously-known-as-programmers-a-guide-for) in front of people *before* we even send them to a different site.

Comment: @BJMyers actually, this one is backwards. It's guidance after they have been sent to the other side.

Answer (score 10):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

One of my most common gripes about questions asked by new(er) users is that the problem statement is something along the lines of "it doesn't work" or "it's not working" (e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55438055/why-isnt-it-retrieving-values-from-database)). Is there any way the wizard can look for these commonly used phrases and provide a polite suggestion that perhaps the problem statement needs some work?

Answer (score 9):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) An addition to [Will's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381677/5515060) talking about writing the title before even writing the question:

> I still think asking for a title at the end is a better option than before writing the question, but placing the tags first is very good.

I propose:

- Let the user input a summary of their question
- Show the user potential duplicates based on their summary
- If no duplicate questions are found, let the user continue writing their question
- Then as a last step:

  - Show the summary they've written and let them select it via checkbox to be their title
  - or allow them to write a new one

Answer (score 9):

Just tried it for the first time and I generally like it!

**To make it perfect for me, the description page would repeat the title I specified.**

My brain works better with this context intact. It helps me elaborate with the same words as used in the title step, instead of using synonyms.

Think of writing an email title, then hiding it when writing the body.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The titles could be misleading since I performed a random test not with a crazy word like [this other answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381680/1426539), but something more common:

[image: idea]

And I got similar answers that well, these kinds of titles could be detected as invalid in the regular system.

[image: normal]

I believe the logic to identify good titles in the regular mode should be reused.

Comment: The "logic to identify good title in the regular mode" is used, for example it doesn't allow title that ends with "!".

Comment: I didn't add any ! if you see, both are the same title @user202729

Comment: @user202729, it seems to allow you to proceed through the wizard.  I did a similar test with the title "Error help with error." and it went ahead and forwarded me to the "Do any of these answer your question?" list.  When I click *back*, it shows the error, but this does seem to be a bug.

Answer (score 7):

The initial screen has the option *I need a software recommendation* then allows the reader to go to [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour).

But if they choose *Show me other options* the top left cell again points to Software Recommendations.

Not only is that redundant, but I think it contributes to the [recent flood of off-topic questions on Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/recent-proliferation-of-how-to-code-questions-superuser-questions).

Given that many off-topic questions on Stack Overflow would be allowed on Super User, Super User should be in that grid of other options.

This adds an additional 'way out' instead of repeating Software Recommendations.

Please replace Software Recommendations with Super User **in that grid**. 
(The order may need to change.) 
(It's fine in the initial screen.)

Comment: We shouldn't remove Software Recs; that's a big pile of questions that would stop getting moved over correctly. However, there may be some merit to adding SuperUser as a fork *in addition*.

Comment: @TylerH It looks like currently some 30% of questions getting 'moved over' are off topic there.

Comment: Well, you’ve proven me wrong. Here I thought it would be the Super User folks who first came with their pitchforks yo protest against an influx of low-quality questions from Stack Overfow. Software Recs wins.

Comment: @JanDoggen A more in-depth look needs to be provided (perhaps in your answer) that considers whether it's the fault of the wizard for misguiding users or the fault of users not listening to either the wizard or the destination site's help center regarding on-topic questions. There needs to be a significant issue, IMO, to make a removal, as the concept of sites handling their own garbage is a much better paradigm than SO handling everyone else's as has unfortunately been the default case for so long.

Comment: @TylerH Agreed. I do not have access to that. Maybe people will contribute under the linked meta question there.

Comment: @JanDoggen Is the Meta question on SoftwareRecs where you got the 30% figure from? I'll try to swing over there and raise the subject if it hasn't been brought up yet.

Comment: @TylerH No that's my very rough estimate after several weeks of (re)visiting the First Post review queue on an irregular basis (from 0 to 3 times a day). I have posted a [meta feature request](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2834/can-we-get-a-close-reason-saying-not-enough-information) today to help speed up the triage.

Comment: @JanDoggen how can you tell these new questions (and the 30% or so that are off-topic) are from people directed to SoftwareRecs from the SO asking wizard?

Comment: @We don't know for sure yet. See the discussion under the meta question. That's why we need more research.

Comment: @JanDoggen I couldn't find a question on the SoftwareRecs meta site discussing the SO Ask Question wizard. Also, after going through the ask question wizard trying to follow your instructions above, I see better what you mean; Super User ought to be in that grid of 5 sites. At the very least, having "Software Recommendations: For software recommendations" is not the most useful description... it should say something that makes it more clear it's for asking for recommendations on what software app/library to use, not general improvements that could be made about software you're writing (for ex)

Comment: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2830/416

Comment: @JanDoggen That's an answer on a question of a different subject, not a question itself.

Comment: @TylerH the related meta question for 30%: [What's up with all the low-quality questions in 2019?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2835) (yeah, it's posted 10 minutes after your last comment on Mar 28...)

Answer (score 6):

I expected the "Show some code" to only be about the code, meaning whatever I write there in any format must always end up as a formatted code, but that was not the case, even though it did turn my text to code, it failed in some parts and I had to post my question and try to fix it the classic way!

**So here are the things I think must be fixed/added to the wizard:**

1. Everything inside the "Show some code" must finally end up as a code no matter how you write it.
2. The wizard doesn't have to follow the restricted editing of the main site, it must be much simpler, its called wizard to allow beginners to post a well formatted Question!, it shouldn't force them to follow the classic and hard way of formatting in Stack Overflow, one example would be that one still can't use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to indent even in the wizard. Which is really annoying.

**My final thoughts:**
I believe the wizard section must have its own editing/tool environment and it shouldn't follow the traditional/classic environment, obviously a conversion from this new environment to the traditional environment happens when the user posts its question, so this medium meaning the wizard can and should become very user friendly without upsetting the old settings.

Comment: Related other answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381796

Comment: Changing the editor too drastically will make it harder for users to learn the traditional editor later, though. Any changes should be done carefully, because they *will* conflict with the traditional header --- inside the user's brain, if not within the technology itself.

Answer (score 6):

Would appreciate *Cancel* button.

Because you know, sometimes you start describing the problem and great idea may come to you and you don't want post question anymore.

It may be some simple icon (a.) or form button (b.) or any other simple and obvious way to cancel whole form:
[image]

Comment: Why can't you just navigate away from the page?

Comment: @CodyGray first what comes to mind to me as user - because in today's "autosave-everything" world, your input can be saved as draft and you need to be sure that form you started to fill is actually erased

Answer (score 6):

GREAT initiative!  I liked how the wizard's form validation would not let me use "I need help with..." in the title.

Suggestion on the sections:  Others have said that it's easy to miss that those sections with the plus signs are sections.  I changed it to use 4 different icons to show some possibilities.  They could be open/close arrows to show that the sections are collapsible.  Or they could be checkboxes to show whether or not the section has any text.

[image: section icon suggestions]

I'd also just add the word Preview above the inline preview.  I put it in orange here so it would be easily noticed.

Answer (score 5):

### An opportunity to reduce edit wars over homework questions

The Answer Wizard has a question type "Homework Question":

> Great! Our community is here to help you with homework questions about
>   code. We’ll take you through a step-by-step guide for writing a great
>   question.
>
> Tip: Focusing on a specific code question - rather than a general
>   homework problem - will help you get fast, high-quality answers. Make
>   sure to have any code handy.

I suggest changing this to:

> Great! Our community is here to help you with homework questions about
>   code. We’ll take you through a step-by-step guide for writing a great
>   question.
>
> Tip: Focusing on a specific code question - rather than a general
>   homework problem - will help you get fast, high-quality answers.
>   Make sure to have any code handy.
>
> Questions and Answers are public and intended to help future viewers. Assume your classmates and course instructor are in the audience. Be at your best when posting or responding to the community.

Reasoning: A frequent headache for homework questions is deletion/edit wars. Someone wants help with *their* homework and does not want to share that help with future viewers, or share evidence that they have violated a course policy by either receiving help or posting course materials without permission. The additional paragraph helps educate new users and reduce misunderstandings without being heavy handed.

Another alternative would be to mix in a similar hint into paragraph 1.

> Great! Our community is here to help you with homework questions about
>   code. While many instructors actively encourage use of Stack Overflow, it is your responsibility to know course policies before posting.
>   All questions and answers are publicly visible. We’ll take you through a step-by-step guide for writing a great question that will help you and your classmates facing similar issues.
>
> Tip: Focusing on a specific code question - rather than a general
>   homework problem - will help you get fast, high-quality answers.
>   Make sure to have any code handy.

Answer (score 4):

I really like it and we've been asking for this for years.

My only feedback is the [Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50464314/why-isnt-an-animation-flipped-horizontally-when-i-call-setflippedtrue) and [Example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50378884/when-catch-doesnt-actually-catch-anything) never change, perhaps a few rotating examples, ideally based on chosen tags.

Answer (score 4):

### Tag page needs better explanation with examples what to do and what not.

---

### [image]

There are two problems:

1. Confusing `X` which can be understood as "don't do that", but version tags are good thing.
2. Poor explanation: "when absolutely necessary" - you could as well remove that line, because it doesn't tells anything useful.

Suggestion:

- Make few "good" and few "bad" examples, perhaps one after another to make it clear what we want.
- Remove version hint or replace with a good quote from answer on meta where version tags are discussed (they were I just can't find the question).

Maybe it's a good idea to keep everything short, but add meta links to **every** statement on every page in the wizard? All those titles, tags, etc. were 100 times discussed.

Answer (score 2):

I had to scroll upwards to see the guiding text when I went from one page to the next -- I might not even see the text if I wasn't paying attention!

For example, after selecting a "Java" tag and hitting "next", I see:
[image: scrolled window]

Comment: I try not to use my laptop screen, but if I make my window as big as it would be on that (1366 x 675px), I'm getting this behaviour too. I don't know if 1366x768 is still a common laptop screen size—hmm, yes, it's the second-most common one on Lenovo's site for my country.

Answer (score 2):

It should be easier to go back to the traditional interface.

Two suggestions for this:

- Add a [user preference](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/). This also covers the possible case where a threshold-passing user prefers the wizard.
- Put a **Use traditional mode** link on the *What type of question do you have?* screen, which is as far back as **Previous** / **Previous Step** will take me.

Current UI behaviour: I must

- press onward through the wizard and, on the four-step *Tell us more about your question* part, click **Use traditional mode**; or
- browse to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?guided=false; or
- **aha! Navigate creatively, to get the *Great!*
  screen to come back up:**

  1. click the **Previous** / **Previous Step** as far back as I can go (the *What type of question do you have?* screen).
  2. Make any choice that leads to Stack Overflow.
  3. Click **Next** to reveal the *Great!* screen, which was skipped over by the last **Previous Step** button and which has the **Use traditional mode** link I needed.

I just found that last one. It was hidden in the bottom-left corner of a screen I couldn't intuitively get to. I mention the bottom-left corner because, in my experience, that's the easiest corner to overlook.

Comment: Going back should be easier, possibly based on rep. I did a quick try because I wanted to play around without posting. And then I was stuck with the wizard. "You have to answer a few Qs first" should take existing answers (look at rep!) into account.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this mentioned in a comment but think it merits being raised if not already:

Sometimes the process of asking a question directly leads to solving the question. Figuring out how to explain things, trying to make a MCVE and struggling when it doesn't have the same behaviour. Heck, sometimes even editing your question when it "unfairly" gets closed causes you to figure out the answer!

In such cases, a way to tell SO/SE this was the case might be great instead of just closing the tab.

Answer (score 0):

When will it be released on localized SO sites?

Comment: Do those sites have the same level of problems with low-quality questions that the original English version of Stack Overflow does? If so, you should probably put together a separate [[meta-tag:feature-request]] to roll it out on these sites.

Comment: @CodyGray should I ask here or on MSE?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. Staff members are supposed to check both places for feature requests. But I'd say it makes the most sense to propose this feature on MSE, since it is not specifically related to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CodyGray ok. But what data do you expect? Will be decision on our local Meta enough? Or we need to provide some sort of metrics?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not the one who makes the decision. Whatever you think will be persuasive. I expect that a consensus from the community will be very persuasive. Perhaps you should begin by posting a feature request on your site-specific Meta to gauge community support? Also, since I left my first comment, I found out some more details. What's actually going to happen is that the best parts (most successful bits) of the Ask Question Wizard [will be incorporated into the standard /ask page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389438), and then that will definitely be rolling out to all sites.

Answer (score -1):

The idea is very good, and also its realization.

What I find particularly wonderful:

- Motivates people to improve, instead of punishing them.
- Helps them to find other SE sites to their off-topic questions, instead closing their questions after they've posted it.
- The problem of many newbies is clearly not only to understand and follow the SE rules, instead they seem simply incapable to understand that we are not an answering machine knowing everything (also what do they think). The wizard seem to care also them.

You are also making a huge improvement on the common intelligence level and communication skills of the humanity on the whole world.

I expect a huge increase in the count of the satisfied newbie visitors.

I think it is your best improvement since many, many years.

Comment: _"You are also making a huge improvement on the common intelligence level and communication skills of the humanity on the whole world."_ That seems like a tiny bit of an overstatement. Just a smidge...

Comment: @Cerbrus Typically, IT is a leading industry world-wide. The impact of the SE/SO world-wide is imho far stronger as it seems. But if you have a better, maybe not so overstatement-like formulation, which still preserves the point, feel free to improve the post.

Comment: I too hope that this feature will help. However, I think I have already seen new authors skipping it. The age-old feature request of spell checkers and waffle detectors are also not delivered, and they may not ever be - so the jury is out on whether the experience of quality on the site will notably improve. I try to be optimistic, but there is an awful lot of woeful material out there.

Comment: @halfer Well, they can skip, but with the reduction of the new crap content, the reviewer resources will probably more focused to the few what remained. And, with the general improvement of the site quality, also the tolerance of the crap will decrease on the long-term. The SE is doing many things badly also in my opinion, particularly these.

Answer (score -1):

## Will this also become available on other Stack Exchange sites?

I did a quick check on [my favorite Stack Exchange site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) and the [Ask a Question page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) has not changed there or a few others.  Are there plans to implement this on all Stack Exchange sites?  How soon?  I am particularly interested in the customizability of such an implementation on other sites, such as the ability to change the sections that are suggested or maybe different tips for each section.  It seems to me that each site has something of it's own community with it's own expectations for how **good** questions are asked, and a customization this tool might be an easy way to improve questions on numerous sites.

## Will there be a CLI for the new guided interface?

Kind of a joke question, but indicative of my overall impression.  There are perhaps too many clicks and too many sections for those of us who are more keyboard-centric.  I would suggest less clicks necessary for the sake of efficiency and sanity.  I mean, *we are programmers here*, let us use our keyboard. :-)

Comment: This is not designed for experienced users, so it doesn't make sense to optimize the interface for efficiency. The most efficient interface is one that isn't guided at all, and that's the one we direct experienced askers to. Regarding other Stack Exchange sites, no, it's not live anywhere else. I don't know if there are plans to adapt it for other sites eventually, but I'm guessing no. It is designed to handle a quality problem writ large on Stack Overflow. Other sites don't suffer from the same problems. Start reading [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/) for background.

Comment: @Cody Gray Thanks for the answer about other sites, but I disagree that other sites don't suffer from poor questions as well.  For example, TeX.SX has a common desire for [Minimum Working Examples (MWEs)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) in questions that could be included in a customized question interface.

Comment: @Cody Gray Can you give a clearer definition of what you call "experienced users"?  Is this solely based on reputation.  If so, which category am I (since I'm asking with a relatively low rep here but enough experience to want less clicks)?  I can see many cases where having an efficient system for new users is also good.  For example, many people read and use Stack Overflow and Exchange sites for a _long time_ before contributing a question.  Are they experienced?  Perhaps they need less guidance due to being patient enough to know what a good question is _before_ trying to ask one.

Comment: I cannot; I do not have a good definition. It is currently based on reputation, as described in the question above, but as you mention, there are certainly other relevant considerations as well. Those would probably be new feature requests.

Answer (score -3):

This looks great, and I am very keen to see some data coming out of this project.

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

In the "title" section of this wizard, there is this advice:

> Say “How to fix ‘Headers already sent’ error in PHP”

That advice is not bad, but since it is suggesting a question for the title, it should end in a question mark, like so:

> Say “How to fix ‘Headers already sent’ error in PHP?”

Comment: Debatable. Is it grammatically a question, or the title of a topic about accomplishing the stated task? (Neither is actually wrong, depending on context.) Does it actually matter?

Comment: That would not be grammatical. "How to x?" is not a question in English. Frankly, it's not a good title at all, because "How to x" isn't even a good English sentence---it's a mere fragment. But to the extent it makes any sense at all, it's declarative, rather than interrogatory. It would need to be, "How do I fix [a] 'Headers already sent' error in PHP?" or "How does one fix [a] 'Headers already sent' error in PHP?" or "How can [a] 'Headers already sent' error be fixed in PHP?". A non-question formulation could be: "Fixing [a] 'Headers already sent' error in PHP".

Comment: @CodyGray: in the suggestion you have made, it becomes worse, since it is better for sentences not to contain "I". We are not specifically interested in helping just one person, and anything that suggests that (helping just the question author) is, to my mind, not ideal. I don't understand how my version is not grammatically correct, but either way, the sentence _is_ there already, and my point is that it _is_ a question, and it needs a question mark. The meaning is unavoidably interrogatory.

Comment: (If the content writers _intended_ this sentence to not have a question mark, then that's fine - though I think this is just an oversight. Whether the sentence should be scrapped entirely and replaced with something else can be raised separately).

Comment: That is my whole point. They obviously intended it not to have a question mark. Putting a question mark there makes it *wrong* and *confusing*, because it's *not a question*.

Comment: We have found out point of disagreement @CodyGray, thank you.

Comment: I generally agree with this, and I agree that "How to __?" feels grammatically acceptable as a question. I'd suggest, upon briefly thinking about it, that the example is not necessarily "unavoidably interrogatory". If I may make so bold, it could have an understood "(Can you tell me) how to [...]?", which would be a question, or it could have an understood "(I'd like to know) how to [...]" or maybe even "(Here's) how to [...]", and those would not.

Comment: @MathieuK.: thanks for your thoughts. I tend to trim "can you tell me" in titles or bodies as it seems to lack personal agency; it seems to be a variant of "please help me out" in which the author has become passive and believes they can no longer help themselves. "How can I" has good agency and is perhaps grammatically preferable, but in titles the "I" strikes me focussing too much on one person - we have long said here that answers are for the community, and not just for the OP.

Comment: I meant that it might be a statement rather than a question, as the part that's understood (i.e. implied) could be "Can you tell me" or it could be "I'd like to know".

Answer (score -4):

On the "What's your question title" page:

[image]

The do-examples read:

- Say “How to fix ‘Headers already sent’ error in PHP”
- Say “Is there an R function for finding the index of an element in a vector?”

To me this looks like it violates the rule "**[Don't include tags in question titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/133056)**".

The above examples could very well read:

- Say “How to fix ‘Headers already sent’ error” (tagged as `php`)
- Say “Is there a function for finding the index of an element in a vector?” (tagged as `r`)

Or am I missing something here?

Comment: The intent behind the rule is to not tag-spam in question titles, or 'tag' questions with the title. Naturally mentioning the technology - whether or not it's already tagged, is fine.

Comment: It *might* be good to add one more example to the list, showing a good title without any tag-words in it, and a bad title with one or more tags artificially attached. But it's not always helpful, or even practical, to try to leave out all mention of language, framework, environment, etc. After all, question titles must be globally unique.

Comment: From the post you linked: *"The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title."* No violation there. A title *should* give context to the question.

Answer (score -6):

Example of the question title uses "tool recommendation" case.

[image]

Given example gives an impression that asking for a function recommendation is not an off-topic on SO.

Comment: Asking for function features is not off-topic. Asking for tool recommendations is off-topic.

Comment: That "good" example would indeed be better phrased as, "How do I find the index of an element in a vector using R?"