# Why are so many recent question titles starting with "Say..."?

Tags: support, title, question-quality, ask-question-wizard-2018

I recently noticed rather unusual pattern in some question titles: these start with word "say", followed by what I would call a real title, in quotation marks.

After noticing pair of such questions I run [this simple search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3asay) and it looks rather popular (I listed some recent examples below). These questions tend to be rather poor but other than that I could not find if they have anything else in common, tags and question texts and askers all look different to me.

What could be the reason to write titles like that, to circumvent some system block on the titles?

---

Examples promised above (most are deleted now but I saved the titles):

- [Say “Program type already present: com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.u”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55739740/say-program-type-already-present-com-google-android-youtube-player-internal-u)
- [Say “How to get data array for a numpy array with python"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55647689/say-how-to-get-data-array-for-a-numpy-array-with-python)
- [Say “How to fix ‘Headers already sent’ error in PHP”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55646934/say-how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)
- [Say “How to know the content of a variable using VB.net”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55615959/say-how-to-know-the-content-of-a-variable-using-vb-net)
- [Say “Is there any code for split the image as two parts in horizontally in JSP”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55613036/say-is-there-any-code-for-split-the-image-as-two-parts-in-horizontally-in-jsp)
- [say“ An error occurred while running a bundle”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55559011/say-an-error-occurred-while-running-a-bundle)
- [Say “_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x06'.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55556632/say-pickle-unpicklingerror-invalid-load-key-x06)
- [Say “how to create the live notification inside the App eg like ”Flipkart bell symbol "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55529576/say-how-to-create-the-live-notification-inside-the-app-eg-like-flipkart-bell-s)
- [Say “Could not find io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-elasticsearch”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55467301/say-could-not-find-io-micronaut-configurationmicronaut-elasticsearch)
- [say “how to reslove this error in python code”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55461219/say-how-to-reslove-this-error-in-python-code)
- [say “Me.CrystalReportViewer1.CachedPageNumberPerDoc = 10” error on form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55455730/say-me-crystalreportviewer1-cachedpagenumberperdoc-10-error-on-form)
- [Say “I am having a slider with seek function for seeking audio files, but it was not smooth while scrolling?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55431413/say-i-am-having-a-slider-with-seek-function-for-seeking-audio-files-but-it-was)
- [Say“how to return back to the while loop after certain condition in if else statement”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55338712/sayhow-to-return-back-to-the-while-loop-after-certain-condition-in-if-else-stat)

Comment: That’s curious… I [asked one of the OPs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55647689/4642212#comment98014916_55647689). I thought this pattern relates to speech-to-text input or text-to-speech output, but it doesn’t seem likely.

Comment: [Mystery solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrD3o.png).

Comment: @CodyGray I am pretty sure non native english speaker won't pay attention to the meaning of *say* here. They probably think it's a way to ask question in english.

Comment: @CodyGray That’s kinda funny. Some of them also seem to have [overlooked steps 2, 3 and 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6jl3.png).

Comment: The "say" in the image means that the OP should type in the title the main motive of his question. That means *don't type this*, *type that*

Comment: @SebastianSimon it didn't *say* you had to do that ...

Comment: I won't lie, this puts a smile on my face :) Ah human beings, never change.

Comment: @CodyGray Consider posting that as an answer

Comment: @SebastianSimon I think "overlooked" may be wrong here - there was discussion recently that "Next" actually posts the question instead of dragging asker through remaining choices (presumably they are expected to click "+" sign)

Comment: You can lead a horse to water ....

Comment: I'm just wondering, why there aren't titles beginning with "_Don't say_" ..?

Comment: @Teemu Because of the icons; they are a perfect indication. I would _say_ (pun intended) that no extra text is needed; the icons do the job.

Comment: Please don't change this - it gives a useful signpost to questions that should be nuked without second thought. (And before "BUT MAH NON-NATIVE-ENGLISH SPEAKERS" - good job at disparaging the non-native-English speakers who *do* manage to actually read 10 centimeters past the ends of their noses.)

Comment: If you see "say" just edit the title of the question..

Comment: @PeterHaddad unfortunately many of such questions are of the kind that can't be meaningfully improved by such an edit. Which isn't surprising since their authors weren't capable to handle even fairly simple grammar used in the wizard UI

Comment: Two days later, one of the questions is at -10 and closed and all the others are deleted. Maybe we could save time by just not posting them :)

Comment: @SebastianSimon That issue is on top of the [wizard feedback post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381678/3579910). I thought it was an easy mistake to make & apparently I'm not alone.

Comment: Now I'm fully expecting to see a few questions that start with "Don't say" ...

Comment: I've also noticed a correlation between posts being deleted by mods and starting with "say".  Every post but one in the examples given has been removed.  SO should add a feature that makes it so a post can't start with "say" or "Q" (just another common one)

Comment: Maybe it's just because **too often** the same title already exists. And adding a "random" word bypasses the *issue*.

Comment: [Real customer be like](https://pics.me.me/brenan-keller-brenankeller-a-qa-engineer-walks-into-a-bar-38583208.png)

Comment: If this puts a smile on @Gimby's face, [it puts a palm on mine](https://google.com/search?q=facepalm&tbm=isch).

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Per discussion in [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382850/what-do-they-say?noredirect=1#comment687706_382850), askers tried [Ask Question Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381671/839601) but it didn't end well:

> [image: screen shot of the title section of Ask Question Wizard]

---

Those of them who got their questions voted down would probably also want to say, "what if the wizard used simpler wording, like *better title / bad title*. Our questions would still be poor mind you, but we probably would avoid some extra downvotes because of the titles".

Comment: I think say should be moved into "For example, say: [examples] But don't say: [examples]" in groups.

Comment: Just remove "say" or "don't say" - the icons work perfectly well without them. You should probably keep them as alt-text for the icons though, for those using screen readers

Comment: Isn't it a bit concerning that most of these questions are utter nonsense _despite_ coming through the wizard?

Comment: Would "do say" instead of "say" be any clearer?

Comment: @Mehrdad It wouldn't prevent the same people from asking terrible questions, so what does it matter?

Comment: @rahuldottech I agree! The icons are a perfect indication of what to use and what not to use, which explains why there are no titles that start with "Don't say".

Comment: Are you sure this is the only reason? I've noticed several cases where it's in the question or even comments that this happen. Could it not be some literal translation from their language?

Comment: @PasserBy what gives it away is not only the inclusion of the word say, but also the double quotes. It's literally following the pattern as presented in the wizard.

Comment: We could just do _Don't say "Say "How to fix 'Headers already sent' error in PHP""_. That will make it clear to everyone.

Comment: @coldspeed In fairness, this is a set of questions pre-filtered down to askers who lack the minimal English comprehension necessary to understand the word "Say" or the meaning of quotation marks. Expecting such users to express a coherent question in English is probably a fantasy, no matter what tools we offer them.

Comment: @coldspeed I feel like it's a feature.  Users are basically self marking bad questions at this point. Now we can basically delete any question with "Say "..."" as the title.

Comment: Just want to add that just icons might have negative implications for accessibility

Comment: Christ. That's really sad. And it just shows that _you cannot help these people_!!