# How long is the suggested edit wait usually?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

I've just received this message on a suggested edit I'm trying to submit on a question.

> The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!

I've tried a few times now, and haven't been able to get my edit onto the review queue.

How long does it usually take for this to clear up, and is it a constant issue?

Comment: It takes 6 to 8 reviewers and a similar 6 to 8 time units to clear some items from the queue.

Comment: It just seems like an unnecessary barrier to submitting suggested edits.

Comment: A user can also only have a maximum of 5 pending edits so I don't think this barrier is unnecessary. But I admit I never hit it.

Comment: It's been like this for at least the past 12 hours.

Comment: Cheers, managed to get it in :)

Comment: They don't want to let the queue get infinitely large since people still have to review these edits. FWIW, it's been a while since someone has said the queue was full on meta so I don't think it gets full often.

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with a [dark mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395999/6083675) bug hindering reviews. The queue isn’t normally so full for so long like this.

Comment: @Laurel All the queues are much larger than they have been for at least a few months. First Post is at 1400.

Comment: I think we are getting even more poor quality questions than usual from people stuck at home. But there aren't more people reviewing so the queue sizes have gone up sharply.

Comment: @greg-449 While you may think that, [it doesn't appear to be true](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394742/is-the-recent-influx-of-home-workers-and-remote-learning-students-impacting-ques)

Comment: @RobertLongson The [site analytics page](https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics) shows that questions are now running quite a bit higher than answers whereas they used to be almost the same.

Comment: Now I'm running into the *The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!* problem.

Comment: @greg-449 I think that it is the [massive-triage-bans effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394498/11336762). Only a little percentage of users is (was) active in reviewing. If thousands of users are banned  this is an expected consequence.

Comment: Well, a lot of parents have less free time now that they’re trying to work and home school at the same time. I imagine a lot of other people have also had their schedule disrupted.

Comment: @Joundill Very true, not everyone is a fan of keeping that tab open for a sometimes longer while just to submit an edit. Especially if, like in my case, you may just write an edit while actually being at work yourself, hence stumbling upon an outdated answer or similar. Etc etc

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [maximum queue size is 500](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351727/how-come-the-suggested-edits-queue-can-suddenly-become-so-big/351728#351728) and it's [currently standing at 437](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats) so you should be able to make your suggested edit now.

I've looked at the 10K [suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/suggested-edits) page and people are still making suggestions and getting them processed. The most recent suggested edit approval was from an edit suggestion from 3 hours ago so it does look like suggestions are still working.

I guess the queue is simply near its capacity so if this happens again, check its size with the above link and have another go when it drops.

Comment: The current amount of suggested edits may vary due to caching. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345157/2735344

Comment: Is the limit per question or is there a global limit for edits of all questions?

Comment: @SimonH it's a global limit. There's also a limit of suggested edits per person.

Comment: The current queue size is 353 right now (20/04/2021) and I can't suggest an edit, it says `The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!`

Comment: After the queue size was around 250 it accepted my edit suggest (20/04/2021)

Comment: I see the queue sits below 500 (434 currently) but I could not make an edit. does the number change? besides review/approve an edit requires to have 2000 reputation. I wonder how many are there both having this value and also active on the site.