# Does each type of review have its own independent queue limit?

Tags: support, tags, review-queues

When trying to submit an edit to a tag usage guidance, I receive the following notice: "The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!".

The edits are then not saved.

Waiting 10 minutes made no difference.

Is this a bug, or is there such a backlog again in that review queue that somehow we've maxed it out?

If we've reached the max, does each type of edit have its own independent limit?  Or is the limit for every review queue 500?  (Thank you Jeanne for the link to that reference.)

By "every queue", I mean does the "Tag Edits" queue have a different limit than the "Suggested Edits" and the "First Posts" queue, et. al.

---

As a side-note, from a UX point of view, the error that the queues are full (or close to full) really needs to be shown before community members spend their valuable time writing edits... that then can't be submitted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long is the suggested edit wait usually?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396865/how-long-is-the-suggested-edit-wait-usually)

Comment: @JeanneDark Thank you.  Sort of.  That was over a year ago.  Is it still a "by-design" issue?  Also, are all the queues independent, or is it 1 giant queue?

Comment: But.. you are >2k... don't your edits apply immediately?

Comment: @Yatin You need [20k+ reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) to edit "tag wikis without needing approval."

Comment: What do you mean with "each queue"? There are different queues, the size of the suggested edits queue [was set to 500 in 2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351727/11682469).

Comment: @JeanneDark Thanks.  I just updated the question to hopefully answer your question.  By "each queue", I mean does the "Suggested Edits" queue have a different limit than "First Posts" and "Tag Edits", et. al.

Comment: There is no "Tag edits" queue. Those go to the regular Suggested Edits queue...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thank you.  I wonder if separating them makes sense. Another option could be when community members with 20K or more rep review Suggested Edits, they get shown tag edits first, as others cannot approve them.

Comment: You're mixing up. Anyone with the editing privilege can edit and review tag edits. 20K users don't need review on tag edits. Similar to how 3k users don't need review for post edits

Comment: @Tomerikoo Ah, thanks.  So I can review tag edits?  I just performed a bunch of reviewing to help try to clear the queue.  I didn't see any tag edits, but maybe that was just the order of the queue.

Comment: Yeah those are pretty rare and additionally there is some kind of priority in the queue I believe that prioritizes regular edits

Comment: No, you cannot review suggested edits to tag wikis and excerpts. You need [5k+ reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) for that.

Comment: Excuse me, folks, but why did we close it against the other question without answers? I know we can do that, but *should* we? I'd expect such a question to be closed only against a Q&A about the suggested edits review queue limit listed (and/or other review queue lengths). I voted to reopen.

Comment: @Tomerikoo - which broke for a day when they rolled out popups with rules recently :) So I was able to review ~20 wiki edits in a row.

Answer (score 1):

> Does each type of review have its own independent queue limit?

Yes, review queues that have limits have separate ones.  It is currently unknown if all queues have limits.

At the time of this writing, the following is the case:

| Queue | Limit | Reference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Close Votes | no known |  |
| First Posts | no known |  |
| Help and improvement | no known |  |
| Late answers | no known |  |
| Low quality posts | no known |  |
| Reopen Votes | no known |  |
| Suggested edits | 500 | [How come the suggested edits queue can suddenly become so big?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351727/how-come-the-suggested-edits-queue-can-suddenly-become-so-big) |
| Triage | 200 | [1, 2, 3...test. Let’s increase the number of reviews & close votes for science!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science/320971) |

<sub>* I wish row spans were supported to group the first six queues, but alas</sub>

Comment: Feel free to correct me if I am wrong - the information is highly fragmented... Especially the "no known" limit part - I couldn't find neither confirmation that there are no limits nor any info saying otherwise (no upper limit for those queues seems logical, though)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Upvoted.  Your first sentence sounds a bit like an oxymoron: "...have separate limits... but not all of them are hard-capped".  If something doesn't have a hard-cap, then it doesn't have a limit, right?  I think perhaps you meant "for some of them, we don't know the limit or if there is one at all".  Would that be more aligned with what you were trying to convey?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket - because it is one :) My bad, I wrote the first half *before* confirming to myself there is no easily discoverable info on any limits in the first six queues. I'll think of something (or somebody will beat me to it, or, if you feel like it - just edit the sentence to something more coherent)

Comment: Ha ha... no problem at all.  I'll edit it for you. :)