# Should we prioritize in-review suggest-edits?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, reputation

### Issue

Reviewing for a lower-reputation user is frustrating. When reviewing with less than 2000 reputation, one has to do a suggest-edit, when trying to improve a post.

This leads to several issues:

1. I can only edit up to five items, and subsequently I am limited in the amount of reviews I can effectively do/have to skip.
2. I am driven away from reviewing at all, as I know I can not do anything for a substantial amount of posts I come across.

It is rather frustrating to edit a post only to get an error for a full suggest-edit queue, as shown below:

[image: Imagine my joy seeing the edit-queue-full-error after fixing a post for several minutes]

Sure I can leave the tab open and just try again later, but that an ineffective workaround at best.

### Proposed Solutions

The current suggest-edit queue has a [limit of 500](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407153/does-each-type-of-review-have-its-own-independent-queue-limit).
I suggest we increase that limit, say to 600 (or whatever is seen as appropriate). But these additional 100 slots would be reserved only for edits made in a review. These 100 review-edits would also get priority when presented in the suggest-edit queue.

Should there be more than 100 review-edits, but less than 500 regular suggest-edits they would "spill over" to the suggest-edit (still prioritized though), if the 500 limit has been reached, the review-edit should fail as it does now.

The reputation limit for instant edits could also be dropped, but I highly doubt this to be done. As far as I know, this hasn't happened yet for any privilege.

---

I know this is not an issue for most people on meta, as most people here already have enough reputation points. But please consider the view of newer users.

Comment: My solution is being no means perfect and I changed from feature-request to discussion. But I can't really think of anything better to improve reviewing for <2k users.

Comment: Get people to be more inclined to do reviews e.g. reward them somehow and reduce the number of pointless edits so reviewing does not seem such a waste of time. To reduce the number of poor suggestions we could use a stick of edit suggestion bans or something similar.

Comment: Yep indeed, the exact reason I don't do Reviews at all anymore, I tried for a while ('First Questions' Review) but I quickly gave up as it's completely pointless with less than 2k-Rep because of the awful 'Suggested Edits' process...

Comment: *"But please consider the view of newer users."* - how many times do you think we have considered it before? I can assure you, you're not the first to come up with a scheme and you're not the first to come up with *this* scheme either. It's kind of a dead end anyway. 10 years ago, a well-received request for change would probably be done 2-5 years down the line. Nowadays - zero chance. The company has their own roadmap and priorities and we're just here to report bugs.

Comment: Re *"I am driven away from reviewing at all, as I know I can not do anything for a substantial amount of posts I come across."*: It is not reviewing in the system sense, but asking clarifying questions in comments if something isn't clear in a post is also a form of review. This may help future readers, including editors in the future. For instance, it may prompt other users to take action.

Comment: I am also <2K here and I also basically gave up editing soon after starting to review here (SO main site), probably for the same reasons as you. I started to read other stacks which were also interesting for me and I made some suggested edits there without coming across the full queue problem. I guess I am generally convinced that the path out of this problem is to get to >2K and then I will just ignore the problem. Maybe if they take the +2 reputation away then the problem will just magically disappear. I would probably start editing again then.

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424490/1456253

Comment: @PeterJames well yes but there is a reason why you need 2k rep which for most users takes a long time to gather - then you have a long time to learn what not to do. Which most users ALSO need, because boy oh boy are we as a species notoriously bad at wanting to find and read instructions.

Comment: The problem is that nobody wants to do reviews, because it is boring, unpaid busy-work and the site owners don't care about the quality of their products, so why should we. That ratio between review-generators and reviewers has been broken for many years. There is no solution that the company would accept, such as paid staff doing reviews and other forms of moderation work.

Answer (score 14):

Edits made outside of review would just sit there forever and never be approved with that model because reviewers would never get to them.

Any real solution needs to address the causes, not the effect.

1. Reviewing edits is not something people are inclined to do very much
2. People make lots of pointless or poor edit suggestions that don't fix things in the post and often make things worse.

Comment: Your second point strongly implies that one should not be trusted with reviews, of not able to decide when to make an edit. I'd rather be barred from reviewing entirely until 2k rep than be in the current limbo.

Comment: My second point is simply an observation after having reviewed over 1200 suggested edits on Stack Overflow. Nobody's forcing you to review anything at all of course. You can just post good content till you get to 2k.

Comment: The claim is that many of the edit suggestions that need to be reviewed are of low quality, @A-Tech , not that the reviewers themselves provide low quality reviews. It only took me a couple of skips to get to a suggestion like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSMm8.png) which "fixes" (adds a load of needed whitespace to) the code block, and introduces spelling and grammar errors. When you *constantly* review *crap* like that, it becomes demoralising pretty quickly.

Comment: At this point I have over 10,000 suggested edit reviews, over 9,000 of them are rejections (although I also skip a lot of marginally good edits). I've not used the queue a lot recently, but edits there these days are not _as_ bad as they were 2 or 3 years ago, but they're still not great.

Comment: @Thom A: It only took me [one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/35490729) (to get to the typical noncomprehensive suggestion that only fixes one thing and leaves the rest (e.g., spelling of "Linux", capitalisation of "i", spelling of "RStudio", run-on sentence, removing meta content, missing (crucial) punctuation, missing words, and spelling of "noninteractive". Most readers could also benefit from some extra punctuation.)).

Comment: It confuses me more that *both* of those edits had approval votes, @PeterMortensen ...