# How could dealing with bad tag wikis be improved for <20k user?

Tags: discussion, flags, suggested-edits, reputation, tag-wiki

Sometimes, I find tag information that is [marketing talk](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24927989), or in other ways, problematic. I usually [try to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33915915). But, being a below 2k user, I frequently cannot make an edit suggestion, and as there is no option to flag a tag, there is nothing I can do.

While "[just getting more rep points](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427735/should-we-prioritize-in-review-suggest-edits#comment983657_427736)" might solve this someday in the future for me, the systemic problem would remain, as I am sure I am not the only <20k user trying to help.

So I thought that tag information should be flaggable as spam, low quality, etc. Perhaps there is another solution as well, so I tagged this with [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion).

Comment: When fixing tag wikis, try to include an explicit section about tag usage guidance. Such as what kind of questions that should be using the tag or which other tags that are recommended to use together with it.

Comment: Just FYI: Editing tag wikis and excerpts without needing the edit to be reviewed is a [20k reputation "Trusted User" privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), not 2k. In addition, it requires [5k reputation to approve tag wiki/excerpt edits](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits).

Comment: If it's *actually* spam, rude/abusive, or plagiarism, then you can flag it just like any other thing that's not a question, answer, or comment: Pick a post, any post (preferably one that's related to the issue or your own), and raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag that explains what the issue is.

Comment: Next month you can ["Discuss" the tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427864/discussions-update-expansion-to-all-tags-in-february). I assume things improve then.

Comment: I'm unsure what you're goal is with this question. There are already a notable number of MSO posts about how inconvenient editing, generally, is when the edit queue is full. There's also a number of [meta-tag:feature-request] questions that suggest tangible changes that would improve the queue overall (e.g., change the "we need reviews done" indicator back to a number) and/or review rates for tag wiki/excerpt edits (e.g., allow >5k users to filter the queue on tag wiki/excerpt edits vs. post edits, so they aren't all mixed together, as there's notably different thinking between such reviews).

Comment: Overall, it feels like you haven't really researched this issue, or at least not presented in the question the results of that research and why you feel the existing questions don't cover what you're asking.

Comment: Have you actually come across any tag wikis that contain spam? I'm sure there are lots that we can agree aren't the best but if we have spam in there then that's a different issue.

Comment: If you find a bad tag wiki you can't fix, the best approach might be to ask about it in a chatroom like [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).

Comment: With respect to your [tag:uppy] tag example, the tag wiki was plagiarized, probably from the uppy.io, but that text has been plagiarized by many other sites, so it could have been copied from somewhere else. I've I've rolled it back to being blank. While I did find the text for the tag excerpt elsewhere, I didn't find a copy that I was able to confirm predated the addition of the text to the tag excerpt.

Comment: (Some context for the example: "[Tus](https://tus.io/faq#what-is-tus)", for *"[transloadit upload server](https://tus.io/faq#what-does-tus-even-mean)"* and later *"[the upload server](https://tus.io/faq#what-does-tus-even-mean)"*)

Comment: @rene: I suppose it could be used in that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just flag the question with the problematic tag as "needs moderator attention" and add your explanation (this flag should come with a text box that lets you do this)

Alternatively I have posted on meta with a link to the problematic tag before (on other SE sites) and it has usually been quickly resolved. You can try this approach as well and someone should be able to fix this (or at least have more people look at it and determine if it really is a problem)